# Что такое stack trace, и как с его помощью находить ошибки при разработке приложений?

Tags: java, android, отладка, java-faq, stacktrace

Иногда при запуске своего приложения я получаю подобную ошибку:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
       at com.example.myproject.Book.getTitle(Book.java:16)
       at com.example.myproject.Author.getBookTitles(Author.java:25)
       at com.example.myproject.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:14)
```

Мне сказали, что это называется «трассировкой стека» или «stack trace». **Что такое трассировка?** Какую полезную информацию об ошибке в разрабатываемой программе она содержит?

---

*Немного по существу: довольно часто я вижу вопросы, в которых начинающие разработчики, получая ошибку, просто берут трассировки стека и какой-либо случайный фрагмент кода без понимания, что собой представляет трассировка и как с ней работать. Данный вопрос предназначен специально для начинающих разработчиков, которым может понадобиться помощь в понимании ценности трассировки стека вызовов.*

<sub>Перевод вопроса: «[What is a stack trace, and how can I use it to debug my application errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3988788/)» [@Rob Hruska](https://stackoverflow.com/users/29995/rob-hruska)</sub>

Comment: ассоциация: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3988788/

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Простыми словами, **трассировка стека** – это список методов, которые были вызваны до момента, когда в приложении произошло исключение.

**Простой случай**

В указанном примере мы можем точно определить, когда именно произошло исключение. Рассмотрим трассировку стека:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
       at com.example.myproject.Book.getTitle(Book.java:16)
       at com.example.myproject.Author.getBookTitles(Author.java:25)
       at com.example.myproject.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:14)
```

Это пример очень простой трассировки. Если пойти по списку строк вида «at…» с самого начала, мы можем понять, где произошла ошибка. Мы смотрим на **верхний** вызов функции. В нашем случае, это:

```
at com.example.myproject.Book.getTitle(Book.java:16)
```

Для отладки этого фрагмента открываем `Book.java` и смотрим, что находится на строке `16`:

```
public String getTitle() {
    System.out.println(title.toString()); <-- line 16
    return title;
}
```

Это означает то, что в приведенном фрагменте кода какая-то переменная (вероятно, `title`) имеет значение `null`.

**Пример цепочки исключений**

Иногда приложения перехватывают исключение и выбрасывают его в виде другого исключения. Обычно это выглядит так:

```
try {
    ....
} catch (NullPointerException e) {
    throw new IllegalStateException("A book has a null property", e)
}
```

Трассировка в этом случае может иметь следующий вид:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: A book has a null property
       at com.example.myproject.Author.getBookIds(Author.java:38)
       at com.example.myproject.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:14)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
       at com.example.myproject.Book.getId(Book.java:22)
       at com.example.myproject.Author.getBookIds(Author.java:35)
       ... 1 more
```

В этом случае разница состоит в атрибуте "Caused by" («Чем вызвано»). Иногда исключения могут иметь несколько секций "Caused by". Обычно необходимо найти исходную причину, которой оказывается в самой последней (нижней) секции "Caused by" трассировки. В нашем случае, это:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException <-- root cause
       at com.example.myproject.Book.getId(Book.java:22) <-- important line
```

Аналогично, при подобном исключении необходимо обратиться к строке `22` книги `Book.java`, чтобы узнать, что вызвало данное исключение – `NullPointerException`.

**Еще один пугающий пример с библиотечным кодом**

Как правило, трассировка имеет гораздо более сложный вид, чем в рассмотренных выше случаях. Приведу пример (длинная трассировка, демонстрирующая несколько уровней цепочек исключений):

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Произошло что–то ужасное
   at com.example.myproject.OpenSessionInViewFilter.doFilter(OpenSessionInViewFilter.java:60)
   at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
   at com.example.myproject.ExceptionHandlerFilter.doFilter(ExceptionHandlerFilter.java:28)
   at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
   at com.example.myproject.OutputBufferFilter.doFilter(OutputBufferFilter.java:33)
   at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
   at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
   at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
   at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
   at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
   at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
   at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
   at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
   at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
   at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:943)
   at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:756)
   at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:218)
   at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
   at org.mortbay.jetty.bio.SocketConnector$Connection.run(SocketConnector.java:228)
   at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
Caused by: com.example.myproject.MyProjectServletException
   at com.example.myproject.MyServlet.doPost(MyServlet.java:169)
   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
   at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
   at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
   at com.example.myproject.OpenSessionInViewFilter.doFilter(OpenSessionInViewFilter.java:30)
   ... 27 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not insert: [com.example.myproject.MyEntity]
   at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:96)
   at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)
   at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractSelectingDelegate.performInsert(AbstractSelectingDelegate.java:64)
   at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2329)
   at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2822)
   at org.hibernate.action.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:71)
   at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:268)
   at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:321)
   at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:204)
   at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:130)
   at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:210)
   at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:56)
   at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:195)
   at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:50)
   at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:93)
   at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.fireSave(SessionImpl.java:705)
   at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:693)
   at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:689)
   at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor5.invoke(Unknown Source)
   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
   at org.hibernate.context.ThreadLocalSessionContext$TransactionProtectionWrapper.invoke(ThreadLocalSessionContext.java:344)
   at $Proxy19.save(Unknown Source)
   at com.example.myproject.MyEntityService.save(MyEntityService.java:59) <-- relevant call (see notes below)
   at com.example.myproject.MyServlet.doPost(MyServlet.java:164)
   ... 32 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Violation of unique constraint MY_ENTITY_UK_1: duplicate value(s) for column(s) MY_COLUMN in statement [...]
   at org.hsqldb.jdbc.Util.throwError(Unknown Source)
   at org.hsqldb.jdbc.jdbcPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(Unknown Source)
   at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(NewProxyPreparedStatement.java:105)
   at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractSelectingDelegate.performInsert(AbstractSelectingDelegate.java:57)
   ... 54 more
```

В этом примере приведен далеко не полный стек вызовов. Что вызывает здесь наибольший интерес, так это поиск функций из *нашего кода*  – из пакета `com.example.myproject`. В предыдущем примере мы сначала хотели отыскать «первопричину», а именно:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException
```

Однако все вызовы методов в данном случае относятся к библиотечному коду. Поэтому мы перейдем к предыдущей секции «Caused by» и найдем первый вызов метода из нашего кода, а именно:

```
at com.example.myproject.MyEntityService.save(MyEntityService.java:59)
```

Аналогично предыдущим примерам, необходимо обратить внимание на `MyEntityService.java`, строка `59`: именно здесь появилась ошибка (в данном случае ситуация довольно очевидная, так как об ошибке сообщает `SQLException`, но в этом вопросе мы рассматриваем именно процедуру отладки с помощью трассировки).

<sub>Перевод ответа: «[What is a stack trace, and how can I use it to debug my application errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3988794/564240)» [@Rob Hruska](https://stackoverflow.com/users/29995/rob-hruska)</sub>

Comment: Стоит добавить что в классе Exception есть конструктор, с параметром cause. С помощью его и образуется цепочка исключений, в которой каждый объект исключений хранит породившего его.