# Tabs android Material Design

Tags: java, android

Подскажите пожалуйста принцип создания tabs в стиле MD. [Пробовал, как здесь](https://www.sitepoint.com/material-design-android-design-support-library/), но у меня ничего не получается. Постоянно вылетает приложение. Если можно, то с маленьким примером. Спасибо.

Вот сама ошибка:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
       Process: com.example.artem_molodcov.twoontwo, PID: 11829
       java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/support/v7/internal/widget/TintManager;
           at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout$TabView.<init>(TabLayout.java:1145)
           at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.createTabView(TabLayout.java:635)
           at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.addTabView(TabLayout.java:669)
           at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.addTab(TabLayout.java:365)
           at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.addTab(TabLayout.java:340)
           at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.setTabsFromPagerAdapter(TabLayout.java:624)
           at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.setupWithViewPager(TabLayout.java:595)
           at com.example.artem_molodcov.twoontwo.MainListActivity.onCreate(MainListActivity.java:51)
           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5975)
           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2269)
           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2376)
           at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:147)
           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1281)
           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5253)
           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:949)
           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:744)
        Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintManager" on path: DexPathList[[dex file "/data/data/com.example.artem_molodcov.twoontwo/files/instant-run/dex/slice-support-annotations-23.4.0_dcdd6768897d75c0d1439daffc3b1358df6baa97-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.artem_molodcov.twoontwo/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_9-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.artem_molodcov.twoontwo/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_8-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.artem_molodcov.twoontwo/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_7-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.artem_molodcov.twoontwo/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_6-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.artem_molodcov.twoontwo/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_5-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.artem_molodcov.twoontwo/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_4-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.artem_molodcov.twoontwo/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_3-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.artem_molodcov.twoontwo/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_2-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.artem_molodcov.twoontwo/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_1-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.artem_molodcov.twoontwo/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_0-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.artem_molodcov.twoontwo/files/instant-run/dex/slice-internal_impl-23.4.0_fe7d3ab8a52aa947417c08c3ae37236e85c4d61a-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.artem_molodcov.twoontwo/files/instant-run/dex/slice-com.google.android.gms-play-services-basement-8.1.0_57f3a6586736edbe7205ae9716f14bb019184c22-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.artem_molodcov.twoontwo/files/instant-run/dex/slice-com.google.android.gms-play-services-appindexing-8.1.0_3a3a0e1fb0f9e5763fd45e331d5ebdf1a01da940-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.artem_molodcov.twoontwo/files/instant-run/dex/slice-com.android.support-support-vector-drawable-23.4.0_234c55a414dbdcd5584df6ee8876d06099cb28b3-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.artem_molodcov.twoontwo/files/instant-run/dex/slice-com.android.support-support-v4-23.4.0_8e2ccdac55547effbded05d725b49a19a8b4c747-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.artem_molodcov.twoontwo/files/instant-run/dex/slice-com.android.su
```

Я еще совсем тупой в области Android разработке. Учусь 3 день. Прошу простить.

Ошибка вот в этом коде(в последней строчке):

```
    DesignDemoPagerAdapter adapter = new DesignDemoPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tablayout);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
```

Вот `build.gradle(module app)`:

```
     dependencies {
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
        compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'
        compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:22.2.1'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:8.1.0'
      }
```

Comment: С каком ошибкой вылетают? Там же вроде бы и так всё подробно расписано

Comment: Если вы не говорите, что за ошибка, значит вы в них не разбираетесь, а значит, с 95% вероятностью у вас `NPE`, т.е. вы невнимательно копировали код из примера и забыли какую-то переменную инициализировать и она у вас `null`

Comment: Пока вы не предоставите **минимальный** пример воспроизведения ошибки (и её тип и строку возникновения (не только номер, но и сам код на ней)) помочь вам невозможно

Comment: Представьте себе, что вам звонит ваша бабушка и говорит, что у неё процессор не работает. Как бы вы могли ей помочь? Никак, пока она не скажет подробностей.

Comment: На какой строке и какая именно ошибка (полный стектрейс) укажите пожалуйста.

Comment: почитайте тут как выяснять что именно у вас за ошибка: [тык](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/510756/17609)

Comment: Приводите ошибку текстом, не скриншотом

Comment: Согласно [тык](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34046525/3212712) проблема может быть в версиях библиотек. Добавьте список зависимостей из `build.gradle(module app)`

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, может код привести и xml разметку?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Скорее всего проблема в различии версий библиотек поддержки. Они должны быть одинаковы и, желательно, самые последние.

Попробуйте так:

```
 dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:8.1.0'
  }
```

---

При этом библиотека для тестов вам, скорее всего, просто не нужна и её можно смело выкинуть:

```
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
```

Comment: Спасибо. 3 раз мне уже помогаете)

Comment: @Артем, пожалуйста. Главное - всегда приводите больше подробностей, не заставляйте нас из вас их клещами тянуть)