# c# windows forms многопоточность

Tags: c#, winforms, многопоточность

Есть программа, в которой есть поток, там что-то исполняется и затем нужно вывести это все в список. Ничего не происходит. Долгими поисками нашел такое решение

```
this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate()
{
    listBox1.Items.Clear();
    listBox1.Items.AddRange(names);

});
```

но такой вариант тоже не подходит, возникает исключение

> "Исключение типа "System.ArgumentNullException" возникло в System.Windows.Forms.dll, но не было обработано в коде пользователя"

Если нажать продолжить, то срабатывает Exception Из моего try/catch, который пишет

> значение не может быть неопределенным. имя параметра: item

Фреймворк версии 4.5. Не понимаю, в чем дело.

p.s. в шарпе недавно, в основном дело имею с джавой

Comment: Хотя нет, там не очень полезный вопрос. Лучше вот этот: [Что такое stack trace, и как с его помощью находить ошибки при разработке приложений?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/510755/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-stack-trace-%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81-%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D1%8C%D1%8E-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6)

Comment: "Есть программа, в которой есть поток, там что-то исполняется и затем нужно вывести это все в список." - для таких задач очень хорошо подходит BackgroundWorker.

Answer (score 0):

Тут у меня есть пример добавления в ListView строки, но, я думаю, Вы разберётесь, как отредактировать код для Ваших целей.

```
private delegate void UpdateListView(String message);

private void btnCreateThread_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Thread thread = new Thread(threadFunction);
    thread.Start();
}

private void threadFunction()
{
    UpdateList add = addListBoxItem;
    String msg = "bla-bla-bla";
    Invoke(add, new object[] { msg });
}

void addListBoxItem(String message)
{
    listBox.Items.Add(message);
}
```

Comment: непонятно, что у Вас в invoke творится:D

Comment: По идее, вызов метода addListBoxItem с передачей параметра-сообщения  :) Вообще код был написан на втором курсе универа, а сейчас мне к нему возвращаться лень, так что вполне может быть, что там полный бред. Но он работал :D

Comment: И как это поможет справиться с ArgumentNullException?

Answer (score 0):

Для полноты картины:

```
public partial class FormMain : Form
{
    public static FormMain EventSend;

    public FormMain()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        EventSend = this;
    }

    public void AppendMessage(string value)
    {
        if (InvokeRequired)
        {
            this.Invoke(new Action<string>(AppendMessage), new object[] { value });
            return;
        }
        listBox1.Items.Add(value);
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Thread thread = new Thread(ForThread.DoIt);
        thread.Start();        
    }
}

class ForThread
{  
    private static void SendMessage(string value)
    {
        FormMain.EventSend.AppendMessage(value);
    }

    public static void DoIt()
    {
        // тут появляется магия вашего потока и генерируются names, 
        // а для примера:
        for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
        {
            string names = i.ToString();
            // И на всякий случай
            if (names != null)
            {
                SendMessage(names);
            }               
        }
    }
}
```

**Update:**

Добавить методы:

```
private void AppendMessage(string value)
{
    if (InvokeRequired)
    {
        this.Invoke(new Action<string>(AppendMessage), new object[] { value });
        return;
    }
    listBox1.Items.Add(value);
}

private static void SendMessage(string value)
{
    AppendMessage(value);
}
```

И вместо

```
this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate()
{
     listBox1.Items.Clear();
     listBox1.Items.Add(names);
 })
```

Вот это

```
 foreach (string name in names)
 {
     if (name =! null)
         SendMessage(name);
 }
```

А *listBox1.Items.Clear();* перед запуском потока в *auth();*

Comment: И как это поможет справиться с ArgumentNullException?

Comment: А тем что, в вопросе непонятно откуда и как берётся "names" и ArgumentNullException может вызвать что угодно, а в приведённом примере явно видна вся цепочка событий - что происходит в потоке и как значение передать на форму.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/bM2bBhx8 вот код

Comment: Обновил код. И проверьте на всякий случай нет ли в массиве names значений null.

Comment: проверил точками останова, if (name != null) не проходит, значит, все имена пустые

Comment: мне кажется дело в парсере html agility, чет он мне не нравится
жаль, в шарпе нет встроенного string парсера, а split тут не подходит
к слову, пробовал и стримрайтером выводить, без делегата соответственно, просто после парса, тоже ничего не выводит. Ну а сплит тут вообще не вариант пользовать, хотя, после его использования, в файл все выводится

Comment: Вероятно, ошибка с NullException и означала, что names отдаются пустыми, хотя до парса resp хранил в себе xml код страницы. Мб, скорее всего, я и неправильно работаю с htmlagility

Comment: @Максим-Фролов проверьте вывод через *for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) { SendMessage( i.ToString());}*. И можно быть уверенным что дело точно не в потоках, а в пустом массиве names