# Не запускается следующее активити

Tags: java, android, xml, activity

У меня не запускается следующее активити. Проблема не в ID элементов. 3аранее спасибо.

Вот ошибка:

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                     Process: kz.yensanova.logika_alemi, PID: 1510
>                     java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
>                         at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
>                         at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:587)
>                         at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:422)
>                         at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:840)
>                         at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2115)
>                         at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:602)
>                         at android.view.View.(View.java:3554)
>                         at android.widget.ImageView.(ImageView.java:123)
>                         at android.widget.ImageButton.(ImageButton.java:87)
>                         at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageButton.(AppCompatImageButton.java:60)
>                         at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageButton.(AppCompatImageButton.java:56)
>                         at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:118)
>                         at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.createView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1021)
>                         at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1080)
>                         at android.support.v4.view.LayoutInflaterCompatHC$FactoryWrapperHC.onCreateView(LayoutInflaterCompatHC.java:47)
>                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:685)
>                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:756)
>                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
>                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
>                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
>                         at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:288)
>                         at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
>                         at kz.yensanova.logika_alemi.ActivityKaz2.onCreate(ActivityKaz2.java:17)
>                         at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
>                         at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
>                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
>                         at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>   I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 1510 SIG: 9
>   Application terminated.

xml-код:

```
<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:background="@drawable/arman"
    android:id="@+id/imageButton151"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="61dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="61dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:background="@drawable/samal"
    android:id="@+id/imageButton152"
    android:layout_marginRight="47dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="47dp"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageButton155"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imageButton151"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/imageButton151" />

<ImageButton
    android:background="@drawable/lupa"
    android:id="@+id/imageButton155"
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="85dp"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageButton153"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageButton154"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/imageButton154"
    android:layout_marginRight="19dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="19dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="23dp" />

<ImageButton
    android:background="@drawable/ertegiler"
    android:id="@+id/imageButton156"
    android:layout_width="90dp"
    android:layout_height="110dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="39dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="39dp"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageButton155"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/imageButton155" />

<ImageButton
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:background="@drawable/fotoapparat"
    android:id="@+id/imageButton154"
    android:layout_width="90dp"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageButton155"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageButton153"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/imageButton153" />

<ImageButton
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    android:background="@drawable/sayakhat"
    android:id="@+id/imageButton157"
    android:layout_width="130dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="7dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="7dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageButton152"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageButton154"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/imageButton154" />

<ImageButton
    android:background="@drawable/talap"
    android:id="@+id/imageButton153"
    android:layout_height="90dp"
    android:layout_width="90dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="58dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageButton152"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/imageButton152" />
```

Java-код второго активити:

```
public class ActivityKaz2 extends AppCompatActivity {
ImageButton imageButton151, imageButton152, imageButton153, imageButton154, imageButton155, imageButton156, imageButton157;
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_kaz2);

    imageButton151 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton151);
    imageButton152 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton152);
    imageButton153 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton153);
    imageButton154 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton154);
    imageButton155 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton155);
    imageButton156 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton156);
    imageButton157 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton157);
    mediaPlayer1 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.eki);
    mediaPlayer1.start();

    imageButton151.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent1 = new Intent(ActivityKaz2.this, Arman.class);
            startActivity(intent1);
            mediaPlayer1.stop();
        }
    });

    imageButton152.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent2 = new Intent(ActivityKaz2.this, Samal.class);
            startActivity(intent2);
            mediaPlayer1.stop();
        }
    });

    imageButton153.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent3 = new Intent(ActivityKaz2.this, Talap.class);
            startActivity(intent3);
            mediaPlayer1.stop();
        }
    });

    imageButton154.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent4 = new Intent(ActivityKaz2.this, Aizere.class);
            startActivity(intent4);
            mediaPlayer1.stop();
        }
    });

    imageButton155.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent5 = new Intent(ActivityKaz2.this, Ayan.class);
            startActivity(intent5);
            mediaPlayer1.stop();
        }
    });

    imageButton156.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent6 = new Intent(ActivityKaz2.this, Kiziltelpek.class);
            startActivity(intent6);
            mediaPlayer1.stop();
        }
    });

    imageButton157.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent7 = new Intent(ActivityKaz2.this, Sarsen.class);
            startActivity(intent7);
            mediaPlayer1.stop();
        }
    });
}
```

P.S: ID были правильно указаны, я просто по ошибке отправила xml-код чернового варианта.

Comment: Проблема в другом. Вы ошибку лучше выложите.

Comment: чтобы дополнить/изменить текст вопроса, нажмите [edit] ниже текста вопроса.

Comment: по всей видимости вашему устройству не хватает оперативной памяти одновременно работать с таким количеством картинок. Нужно оптимизировать их размер под разные разрешения экранов.

Answer (score 3):

Ответ на вопрос дал **Suleymanovtat**, Вы ищите в xml не те объекты. Я хотел его дополнить несколькими советами. Чтобы Вам и нам было проще решить Вашу проблему, Вам следует сделать следующие вещи:

1. Посмотрите о [Logcat](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cCmkOQcOex4),
   сюда выпадают все ошибки. Если приложение непонятно почему крашится,
   в колонку `Error` пишется **стектрейс**. Это последовательность
   вызова методов до прихода к ошибке. Прочитайте о нем тут -
   [стектрейс](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/510755/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-stack-trace-%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81-%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D1%8C%D1%8E-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6).

   Logcat работает только тогда, когда Вы запускаете программу на
   реальном устройстве (с подключенным USB кабелем и режимом откладки) или просто на эмуляторе. С данным вопросом можно повозится, но инструкций в этом плане очень много.
2. Как только разберетесь со стектрейсом, перед тем, как задать вопрос сюда - "гуглите" название появившейся ошибки. В данной ситуации у Вас появлялась `NullPoinerException`, самая популярная ошибка. Она означает, что Вы обращаетесь к объекту, который `null`, то есть НЕ инициализирован.
3. Исходя из ошибки Вы можете понять, что метод `findViewById` не вернул Вам объект, а просто его не нашел. Есть удерживать `Ctrl` и нажать ЛКМ на методе - Вам перенесет к нему, а уже у него есть документация, где описываются случаи возвращения `null`. **Мораль: всегда читайте документацию к используемым методам и классам.**
4. И почитайте о [конвенциях кода](https://source.android.com/source/code-style). Это стандарт написания, Ваш код становится легче читать всем, включая Вам.

100% вопросов, которые Вы захотите задать в ближайшие пол года, Вы в состоянии решить сами. Просто ищите в интернете и пытайтесь разобраться **из-за чего** произошла ошибка. И ищите на английском. На нем легче найти ответ, даже если Вы плохо знаете английский (сам не верю, но это так... :)). Базовые вещи сверху обязательны и будут экономить Ваше время.

P.S. И вопросы нужно дополнять кнопкой "править" под вопросом. Не мучайте нас.

Answer (score 2):

проблема в следующем, id не соответствует действительности, проверь id,  у тебя в xml указан один Id, а в коде используется другой  id, подправь вот так(ниже код), и на будущее называй id осмысленно

```
imageButton151 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton3);
imageButton152 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton4);
```

Answer (score 1):

ошибка OutOfMemory появляется когда нехватает оперативной памяти для приложения.я программирую приложение и тестирую его не на эмуляторе а на реальном устройстве и такой ошибки ни разу небыло, но видимо она у меня постоянно когда пытаюсь поиграть в игры (у меня 400~ МБ памяти). рекомендую вам уменьшить разрешение(качество) изображений в несколько раз , или увеличить память для эмулятора, или запустить на другом устройстве