# Проблема в подключении adnroid приложения к локальному серверу

Tags: android, сеть, сокет

Здравствуйте. При создании android приложения, которое должно связываться с локальным javа сервером(соединение проходит в локальной сети), возникла следующая проблема. При открытии приложения, на сервер отправляется тестовое сообщение, свидетельствующее о том, что приложению на телефоне удалось подключиться к серверу на пк, а далее приложение выдает ошибку и закрывается. В чем заключается ошибка так и не удалось понять, надеюсь на вашу помощь. За ранее спасибо за помощь[image: ![введите сюда описание изображения]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cYRxy.jpg)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код клиента на android:

1)Класс отвечающий за соединение с сервером.

```
public class ClientConnection implements Runnable{
public Socket socket;
public BufferedReader in;
public PrintWriter out;

private TextView t;

Date date;
DateFormat df;
String now;

public ClientConnection(TextView t){
    this.t = t;
}

public void setNet() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    try {
        socket = new Socket("192.168.1.49", 8080);
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
        out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());

    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public void run(){
    setNet();
    try {
        sendMessage("hello from android!");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    while(socket.isConnected()){
        try {
            now = df.format(date);
            t.append(" " + now + " " + getMessage() + "\n");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.print("ошибка");
        }
    }
    try {
        socket.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void sendMessage(String message) throws IOException{
    out.println(message);
    out.flush();
}

public String getMessage() throws IOException{
    return in.readLine();
}}
```

2)Главная активность

```
public class DialogActivity extends Activity {

Button sendButton, smileButton;
EditText inputText;
TextView dialogView;
ClientConnection cc;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_dialog);
    sendButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.sendbutton);
    dialogView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.dialogview);
    inputText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);

    sendButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dialogView.append(" " + inputText.getText() + "\n");
            inputText.setText("");
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    ClientConnection cc = new ClientConnection(dialogView);
    Thread t = new Thread(cc);
    t.start();
}}
```

Код сервера на локальном пк:

```
public class Connection extends Thread{


public Socket clientConnection;
public BufferedReader in;
public PrintWriter out;

public JTextArea chatArea;
public String date;

public Connection(Socket socket){
    clientConnection = socket;

    try {
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientConnection.getInputStream()));
        out = new PrintWriter(clientConnection.getOutputStream());
        start();
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


public void run(){
    while(clientConnection.isConnected()){
        try {
            chatArea.append(date+"client: " + getMessage() + "\n");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    try {
        clientConnection.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void setArea(JTextArea textArea){
    this.chatArea = textArea;
}

public void setDate(String string){
    this.date = string;
}

public void sendMessage(String message) throws IOException{
    out.println(message);
    out.flush();
}

public void sendMessageToConnection(String message, Connection conn){
    conn.out.println(message);
    conn.out.flush();
}


public String getMessage() throws IOException{
    return in.readLine();
}}
```

Comment: Без сообщения об ошибке и указания строки возникновения оной - как вам помочь?.. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/510755/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-stack-trace-%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81-%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D1%8C%D1%8E-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6/510756#510756

Comment: В том-то и дело, что сообщения об ошибке в логах нет, поэтому нет и указания на строку в коде:D. Именно поэтому и задал вопрос, надеясь на то, что может кто-нибудь сталкивался с подобным :)

Comment: Значит не так смотрите. Не бывает вылета без логов. И проверьте что у вас `now = df.format(date);` не `null` все переменные

Comment: Все, проблему решил. Тему можно закрыть:D

Comment: удет хорошо, если вы опишите в чём была проблема и как вы её решили в ответе на свой вопрос - это может пригодиться будущим посетителям страницы, которые придут сюда из поисковиков)