# Пример приложения не работает

Tags: android, android-studio

делал пример приложения - загрузка файла изображения из интернета с помощью библиотеки Glide. Ничего не получается, после нажатия кнопки загрузки приложение "падает"

Совершенно точно уверен в правильности кода, манифест разрешает загрузку из интернета, компиляция без ошибок и предупреждений...
Для эксперимента убрал Glide и использовал Picasso, все сработало идеально.

Помогите понять в чем ошибка, мне все таки нужна Glide для загрузки изображений и mp3

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ImageView mImageView;
    private String mImageAddress =
            "http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/images/android_cat.jpg";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    }

    public void onClick(View view) {
        // Загружаем картинку
        Glide
                .with(this)
                .load(mImageAddress)
                .into(mImageView);
    }
}
```

Comment: Если "падает", значит есть стектрейс. Его нужно приложить к вопросу

Comment: Подскажите как, там много строк и сложно сюда добавить

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/510756/177345

Comment: ругается на Glide.with(this) - на этой строке появляются ошибки моего приложения

Comment: видимо методу требуется контекст, но this в колбэке очевидно не ссылка на активити(контекст), но точно сказать в чем именно проблема без стектрейса нельзя. попробуйте использовать вместо this: getContext(),  MainActivity.this или другие способы получения контекста. Прикладывайте к вопросу стэктрейс, а не просто указание строки, которая вызвала падение, телепатов здесь обычно не бывает

Comment: глайд так и не настроил, не получилось. Использую пискассо, пока работает без ошибок. А вызов контекста решил через holder.imgObl.getContext()