# Andoid studio 3.0.1 При добавлении Image view приложение вылетает

Tags: android, android-studio

Что делать?

Единственный активити (xml)

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.mrfair.domasnitsklad.MainActivity"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="81dp">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/code"
        android:layout_width="214dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="99dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="98dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="number"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/contentedit"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.481"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginRight="99dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="98dp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/contentedit"
        android:layout_width="363dp"
        android:layout_height="124dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/list"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.481"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ListView"
        android:layout_width="371dp"
        android:layout_height="231dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="88dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.481"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/pin03"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="16dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="432dp"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Единственный активити (java)

```
package com.example.mrfair.domasnitsklad;

import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    SharedPreferences sPref;
    TextView content;
    EditText code;
    String codetext;
    ListView list;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        code = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.code);
        content = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.contentedit);
        list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
    }

    public void readFile (View v) {
        codetext = code.getText().toString();
        sPref = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
        String saved_text = sPref.getString(codetext, "");
        content.setText(saved_text);
        String[] str = saved_text.split(" ");
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.names,str);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
    public void newfile (View v){
        sPref = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
        codetext = code.getText().toString();
        String conttext = content.getText().toString();
        boolean bool = sPref.getBoolean(codetext, true);
        if (bool){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Ошибка", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        } else if (!bool){
            SharedPreferences.Editor et = sPref.edit();
            et.putString(codetext, conttext);
            et.apply();
        }


    }
    public void deletefile (View v) {
        codetext = code.getText().toString();
        sPref = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor et = sPref.edit();
        et.remove(codetext);
    }
    public void savefile (View v) {
        sPref = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
        codetext = code.getText().toString();
        String conttext = content.getText().toString();
        sPref = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor et = sPref.edit();
        et.putString(codetext, conttext);
        et.apply();
    }
    public void undo (View v){
        codetext = code.getText().toString();
        sPref = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
        String saved_text = sPref.getString(codetext, "");
        content.setText(saved_text);
    }
}
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/510755/Что-такое-stack-trace-и-как-с-его-помощью-находить-ошибки-при-разработке-прилож

Comment: post_zeew не помогло

Comment: что не помогло то? стэктрейс ошибки в вопрос добавьте.

Comment: Замените `app:srcCompat` на `android:src`