# Приложение вылетает при вызове фрагмента через BottomNavigationBar

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragment, bottom-navigation-view

Добрый вечер. Я сделал приложение с BottomNavigationBar, с помощью которого хочу переключаться между фрагментами, но когда я переключаюсь на фрагмент, приложение вылетает. Как можно решить, или хотя бы как понять, в чём именно проблема?

Код вызова фрагмента:

```
case R.id.navigation_museums:
mTextMessage.setText(R.string.title_museums);
MuseumsFragment mf = new MuseumsFragment();
FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.replace(R.id.main_view, mf, "museum");
ft.commit();
return true;
```

Comment: приведите стектрейс ошибки

Comment: Чтобы понять, в чем именно проблема, нужно посмотреть [стектрейс при падении](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/510756/177345). Если все еще не понятно, то добавить его в вопрос, так как без него никто вам не скажет, в чем ваша проблема, эктрасенсорные способности в наше время развиты крайне недостаточно.