# Проблема с изменением ориентации экрана

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, orientation

у меня есть приложение в котором еще не прописан процесс изменения ориентации экрана. я решил попробовать изменить ориентацию, думая что все элементы могут просто разместиться не правильно или сбиться в кучу, но как результат у меня приложение закрылось и вывело сообщение что произошла ошибка. я теперь не знаю как мне прописать правильно layout что бы эта ошибка пропала и ориентация менялась корректно. Возможно я не сильно понятно объяснил свой вопрос в комментариях могу уточнить что будет не понятно. Код ошибки

```
03-07 12:46:11.482 7969-7969/com.example.andrew.mm E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main                                                                 Process: com.example.andrew.mm, PID: 7969                                                                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.andrew.mm/com.example.andrew.mm.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.example.andrew.mm.MainActivity$ThreadConnected.write2(byte)' on a null object reference
     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2509)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2569)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4423)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:150)
     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1405)
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:168)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5885)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:797)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:687)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.example.andrew.mm.MainActivity$ThreadConnected.write2(byte)' on a null object reference
     at com.example.andrew.mm.MainActivity$1.onCheckedChanged(MainActivity.java:90)
     at android.widget.RadioGroup.setCheckedId(RadioGroup.java:173)
     at android.widget.RadioGroup.access$600(RadioGroup.java:53)
     at android.widget.RadioGroup$CheckedStateTracker.onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup.java:351)
     at android.widget.CompoundButton.setChecked(CompoundButton.java:159)
     at android.widget.CompoundButton.onRestoreInstanceState(CompoundButton.java:548)
     at android.view.View.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(View.java:14854)
     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:3139)
     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:3139)
     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:3139)
     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:3139)
     at android.view.View.restoreHierarchyState(View.java:14832)
     at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.restoreHierarchyState(PhoneWindow.java:2058)
     at android.app.Activity.onRestoreInstanceState(Activity.java:1015)
     at android.app.Activity.performRestoreInstanceState(Activity.java:970)
     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnRestoreInstanceState(Instrumentation.java:1187)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2482)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2569) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4423) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:150) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1405) 
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:168) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5885) 
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:797) 
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:687)
```

Comment: Приложите в вопрос [стектрейс при падении](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/510756/177345) (вкладка logcat внизу) и связанный с этим код (место, где произошла ошибка). Добавляйте информацию в вопрос, нажав кнопку "править" под вопросом, а не в комментариях к нему.

Comment: Добавьте код вашей `MainActivity` и укажите, где в нём 90 строка.

Comment: Может я добавлю часть кода с этой строкой потому-что много получается