# Передать данные из базы даных в drop down list (spinner)

Tags: java, android, android-spinner, dropdown

Здравствуйте. У меня есть две activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  implements View.OnClickListener {
EditText ename,eroll_no,emarks/*, gr*/;
Button add,view,viewall,delete,modify, groupe, addcat;
Spinner gr;
SQLiteDatabase db;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ename = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.name);
    eroll_no = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.roll_no);
    emarks = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.marks);
    //gr = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.gr);
    gr = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);// сам спиннер из вида
    add = (Button)findViewById(R.id.addbtn);

    db = openOrCreateDatabase("Student_manage", Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS student(rollno INTEGER UNIQUE,name VARCHAR,marks INTEGER,groupe VARCHAR);");
    //вот я пытаюсь сделать:
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM groups", null);
    SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, cursor, new String[] {"name"}, new int[] {android.R.id.text1});       adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    gr.setAdapter(adapter);
    add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       //тут уже другой код
    }
}
}
```

И вторая activity:

```
public class GroupActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    SQLiteDatabase db;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_group);

        db = openOrCreateDatabase("Student_manage", Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS groups(_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,rollno INTEGER UNIQUE,name VARCHAR);");
        adds.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            //тут уже другой код
        }
    }
}
```

Сейчас приложение даже не компилируется. Что я делаю не так?

Logcat пишет:

```
нет _id
```

Comment: @pavlofff добавил описание ошибки

Comment: Если устанавливается и падает с ошибкой на устройстве, значит все же нормально компилируется. Внизу в студии есть вкладка logcat, когда напишет, что в приложении произошла ошибка - смотрите туда и [копируете стектрейс](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/510756/177345) сюда (блок где фигурируют слова execption, caused by и at, а не весь лог), так же в какой строке ошибка (в logcat ссылка на нее подсвечена синим и кликабельна)

Comment: @pavlofff добавил описание ошибки

Comment: @pavlofff  причина была в опечатке и не было _id primary key

Comment: @pavlofff   можете подсказать еще по одному вопросу? я опубликовал его ниже

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Нашел решение.**
Все моя невнимательность, в другой таблице искал, поправил:

```
Cursor cursor = db.query("groups", new String[]{"_id","name"}, null, null, null, null, null);
```