# У меня просят стектрейс (Stack Trace) или логкат (Logcat). Что это?

Tags: android, android-studio, терминология, stacktrace

Я разрабатываю приложение и оно не работает. На экране появляется надпись "Unfortunately App has stopped" ("Приложение остановлено") и ничего не происходит.

Задав вопрос, у меня спросили стектрейс в логкат, но я не знаю, что это и где его взять?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Для того, чтобы получить так нужный для решения проблемы стектрейс, рассмотрим скриншот:

[image: screen]

Теперь делаем следующее. После того, как на экране появилась пессимистичная табличка, что приложение остановилось и работать дальше не будет, в Android Studio нажимаем на вкладку внизу с названием Logcat (пункт 1 на скриншоте) или на быструю клавишу *6*. При этом мы должны убедится, что соединение IDE с устройством у нас установлено, а лог мы читаем из потока нашего тестируемого приложения (пункт 2 на скриншоте) - здесь мы видим, что подключены к эмулятору Nexus S к процессу *com.examle.raschet* - это наше неработающее приложение.

Но лог очень большой, как понять, что именно нам нужно показать другим (или прочитать самому), чтобы понять, в чем причина остановки приложения?

В этом нам помогут ключевые слова, подчеркнутые желтой линией: *exception* и *caused by*, так же верным признаком, что то, что нам нужно рядом, является ссылка синего цвета (пункт 3 на скриншоте), обычно с названием класса, в котором появилась ошибка (ссылки серого цвета ведут к системным классам и в решении нашей проблемы носят информационный характер, так как править системные классы мы все равно не будем) и PID процесса нашего приложения в логе (здесь 3867, смотреть в пункт 2 на скриншоте). Здесь нам указывают, что проблема на строке 19 (пункт 4 на скриншоте), если кликнуть мышью на эту синюю ссылку, то мы перейдем к проблемной строке в редакторе кода.

Теперь нам нужно скопировать весь блок, начиная от строки с датой и временем, где есть exception и ссылка на наш класс с ошибкой и до следующей строки с датой и временем (от отметки *03-13 03:18:02.654* до отметки *03-13 03:18:02.656*). Так же необходимо добавить в вопрос и ту строку кода, на которую ссылается стектрейс (у нас это строка 19), если проблему вы будете решать не самостоятельно.

Данный ответ не ставит целью объяснить, как решить проблему, а только как получить лог для ее решения. Попытаться самому разобраться, что написано в стектрейсе вы можете, почитав этот [замечательный ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/510756/177345).