# почему когда присваиваю последний сегмент "content uri" к переменной, приложение останавливается?

Tags: android, события, calendar, android-alarm-manager, uri

Так работает:

```
void strt(){
    Calendar beginTime = Calendar.getInstance();
    beginTime.set(2018, 2, 14, 7, 30);
    Calendar endTime = Calendar.getInstance();
    endTime.set(2018, 2, 15, 8, 30);

    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT)
            .setData(CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI)
            .putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_BEGIN_TIME, beginTime.getTimeInMillis())
            .putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_END_TIME, endTime.getTimeInMillis())
            .putExtra(CalendarContract.Events.TITLE, "Yoga")
            .putExtra(CalendarContract.Events.DESCRIPTION, "Group class")
            .putExtra(CalendarContract.Events.EVENT_LOCATION, "The gym")
            .putExtra(CalendarContract.Events.AVAILABILITY, CalendarContract.Events.AVAILABILITY_BUSY)
            .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, "rowan@example.com,trevor@example.com");




   Uri uri = CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI;
   //long eventID = Long.parseLong(uri.getLastPathSegment());
```

но когда добавляю строку

```
long eventID = Long.parseLong(uri.getLastPathSegment());
```

происходит сбой в приложении, даже не запускается.
П.С.
мне нужно получить eventID, чтоб установить напоминание...

Comment: наверное вам андроид студия вам что-то пишет в logcat когда приложение падает, добавьте logcat в вопрос: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/797531/%d0%a3-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d1%8f%d1%82-%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b9%d1%81-stack-trace-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%82-logcat-%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%8d%d1%82%d0%be

Comment: потому, что метод getLastPathSegment() возвращает String, который вы пытаетесь присвоить переменной типа long.

Answer (score 0):

Вообщем проблема в том, что к "uri"- "CalendarContract.Events", не присвоен ID (целые числа).
Это скорее всего можно сделать так:

```
ContentUris.withAppendedId(Events.CONTENT_URI, eventID);
```

где eventID=

```
long eventID = 188;
```