# создание перехода по кнопке с fragment на activity. Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-fragment, activity

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]в проекте 3 фрагмента, в фрагменте есть кнопка, если нажать эту кнопку тебя должно перенести на отдельное активити, вопрос как? прописал в классе первого фрагмента (откуда должен быть переход)

/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class BlankFragmentTab2 extends Fragment {

```
public BlankFragmentTab2() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blank_fragment_tab2, null);
    final Button shl2 = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.shl2);
    View.OnClickListener onClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            switch (view.getId()) {
                case R.id.shl2:
                    Intent intent = new Intent(BlankFragmentTab2.this.getActivity(), test.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    break;
            }
        }
    };
    shl2.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment


    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blank_fragment_tab2, container, false);
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

Ошибка здесь:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(BlankFragmentTab1.this.getActivity(), notes.class);
```

Вторым параметром в интент нужно передавать класс активити на которую вы переходите. Вы же передаете `notes.class`, где `notes` - это ваша кнопка `Button`.

Должно быть примерно так:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(BlankFragmentTab1.this.getActivity(), АктивитиНаКоторуюПереходите.class);
```

Comment: скрольните вправо

Comment: @fantik что скрольнуть? что вы имеете ввиду?

Comment: у меня написано так, как вы сказали

Comment: @fantik  вы наследуете свои активити от `Button`? Проверьте свой код, вы хотите перейти на кнопку, со всеми вытекающими последствиями. Вместо `notes` во втором аргументе интента вам нужно указать класс вашей активити. Прочитайте внимательно ответ еще раз.

Comment: посмотрите сейчас, тоже не работает

Comment: @fantik покажите название класса (java файла) активити на которую вы переходите?

Comment: скриншот подойдет?

Comment: @fantik ок, тогда еще покажите стэктрейс ошибки, которую получаете при нажатии кнопки

Comment: не подскажите как найти этот стэктрэйс

Comment: @fantik [смотрите здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/797531/%D0%A3-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%8F%D1%82-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%81-stack-trace-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82-logcat-%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE)

Comment: интересно то, что ошибки не возникает при нажатии на кнопку