# Переход по кнопке с фрагмена на активити

Tags: android, android-fragment, activity, button, onclicklistener

```
@Override 
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

     View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blank_fragment_tab1, null);

     Button btn_notes = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.btn_notes);

     View.OnClickListener oclBtnOk = (new View.OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {

             Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), notes.class);
             startActivity(intent);
         }
     });

     btn_notes.setOnClickListener(oclBtnOk);

     return v;//inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blank_fragment_tab1, container, false);
 }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]Парюсь с этим очень долго, никак не могу найти как осуществить переход по кнопке используя listener, можно пожалуйста пример кода.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: код нужно добавлять в ответ в виде отформатированного текста, а не скриншотов.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [создание перехода по кнопке с fragment на activity. Android Studio](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/804358/%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%ba%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%ba%d0%b5-%d1%81-fragment-%d0%bd%d0%b0-activity-android-studio)

Answer (score 0):

```
awesomeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
      startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), AwesomeActivity.class));
   }
});
```

где

- `awesomeButton` - ваше кнопка, на которую вешаете слушатель
- `AwesomeActivity` - активити, которую вы хотите запустить

Comment: а можно полный код?

Comment: @fantik, куда полнее? За вас написать проект?) Что именно вам непонятно в куске кода, где на кнопку вешается слушатель нажатий?

Comment: ну вот я попытался, ошибок нет, как и перехода на активити. докинул скрин

Comment: @fantik, покажите, что за класс notes. Это Activity? Она в манифесте объявлена?

Comment: обычная activity созданная вместе с layout, в манифесте объявлена.

Comment: @fantik, поправил ответ

Comment: тоже не канает.

Comment: @fantik, задача совсем уж тривиальная. У вас во внутрь метода onClick заходит вообще?

Comment: вот еще заколхозил, ничего не помогает.