# XML from URL XmlPullParser

Tags: java, android, xml, xmlparser

Просьба не  ругать сильно, с XML не работал, только учусь. 
Пока иду от простого XmlPullParser что бы понять принцип работы.
Собственно сам вопроос: 
Разбираю документ с сайта, из него нужно выдернуть несколько полей и добавить к ключу запрос хэдер. 
есль файл расположен локально в проекте, вопросов нету , я разобрался.
Но вот пытаюсь все то же самое выдернуть из сети и не получается.
+ не совсем до конца понимаю каки правильно приложить хэдер. ( через браузер делаю, ответ вижу)
Собственно сам код

```
listView = findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    new GetWeatherDataTask(this, URL_CONNECT).execute();
```

и бэкграунд такой:

```
public class GetWeatherDataTask extends AsyncTask<String[], Void, List<Employee>> {

    private MainActivity activity;
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    public GetWeatherDataTask(MainActivity activity, String url) {
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(activity);
        pDialog.setTitle("Get Weather Information from XML");
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        pDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected List<Employee> doInBackground(String[]... params) {
        try {

            URL url=new URL("https://rasp.rw.by/api/ru/index/route/?from=Иваново&to=Москва");
            HttpURLConnection connection=(HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();

            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.setRequestProperty("X-AppId", "97377f7b702d7198e47a2bf12eec744d5");

            connection.connect();
            InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();

            XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
            factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
            XmlPullParser  parser = factory.newPullParser();
            parser.setInput(is, "UTF-8");

            parser.setFeature(XmlPullParser.FEATURE_PROCESS_NAMESPACES, true);

            int eventType = parser.getEventType();

            while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
                String tagname = parser.getName();
                //index рабочий тег
                if (eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
                    if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("index")) {

                        //на теге индекс начинаем выдергивать
                        employee = new Employee();
                        employees.add(employee);
                    }


                }else

                if (eventType == XmlPullParser.TEXT) {
                    text = parser.getText();
                }else

                if (eventType ==  XmlPullParser.END_TAG) {

                    if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase(TITLE)) {
                        employee.setId(text);
                    } else
                    if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase(TRAIN_NUMBER)) {
                        employee.setTrain_number(text);
                    } else
                    if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase(TRAIN_DAYS)) {
                        employee.setTrain_days(text);
                    } else
                    if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase(MIN_PRICE)) {
                        employee.setMin_price(text);
                    } else
                    if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase(FROM_TIME)) {
                        employee.setFrom_time_formatted(text);
                    } else
                    if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase(TO_TIME)) {
                        employee.setTo_time_formatted(text);
                    } else
                    if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase(TRAIN_STOPS)) {
                        employee.setName(text);
                    } else
                    if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase(DURATION)) {
                        employee.setSalary(text);
                    }

                }

                eventType = parser.next();
            }

        } catch (XmlPullParserException | IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("AsyncTask", "GOOD");
            Log.e("AsyncTask", String.valueOf(employees));

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("AsyncTask", "exception");
            return null;
        }
        return employees;
    }




    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<Employee> result) {
        pDialog.dismiss();
        ArrayAdapter<Employee> adapter =new ArrayAdapter<Employee>
                (getApplicationContext(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, employees);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    }


}
```

собственно в логи выводится `Log.e("AsyncTask", "GOOD"); и []`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[_body:protected] =>

```
[_directory:protected] => Api
```

05-10 16:04:01.711 24921-25023/com.roman.xml E/AsyncTask:                                             [_controller:protected] => Index
05-10 16:04:01.711 24921-25023/com.roman.xml E/AsyncTask:                                             [_action:protected] => route
05-10 16:04:01.711 24921-25023/com.roman.xml E/AsyncTask:                                             [_uri:protected] => api/ru/index/route
05-10 16:04:01.711 24921-25023/com.roman.xml E/AsyncTask:                                             [_external:protected] => 
05-10 16:04:01.711 24921-25023/com.roman.xml E/AsyncTask:                                             [_params:protected] => Array

```
(
```

05-10 16:04:01.711 24921-25023/com.roman.xml E/AsyncTask:                                                     [lang] => ru
05-10 16:04:01.711 24921-25023/com.roman.xml E/AsyncTask:                                                     [lang_sensitive] => 1
05-10 16:04:01.711 24921-25023/com.roman.xml E/AsyncTask:                                                     [domain] => api
05-10 16:04:01.711 24921-25023/com.roman.xml E/AsyncTask:                                                     [debug] => 
05-10 16:04:01.711 24921-25023/com.roman.xml E/AsyncTask:                                                 )
[10] => Array
05-10 16:04:01.720 24921-25023/com.roman.xml E/AsyncTask:                 (
05-10 16:04:01.721 24921-25023/com.roman.xml E/AsyncTask:                     [file] => /home/rasprwby/rasp.rw.by/www/index.php
05-10 16:04:01.721 24921-25023/com.roman.xml E/AsyncTask:                     [line] => 118
05-10 16:04:01.721 24921-25023/com.roman.xml E/AsyncTask:                     [function] => execute
05-10 16:04:01.721 24921-25023/com.roman.xml E/AsyncTask:                     [class] => Kohana_Request
05-10 16:04:01.721 24921-25023/com.roman.xml E/AsyncTask:                     [type] => ->
05-10 16:04:01.721 24921-25023/com.roman.xml E/AsyncTask:                     [args] => Array

Comment: А перед Вашим `"GOOD"` что красным шрифтом написано в логах? В общем с Вас [стектрейс ошибки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/797531/11515).

Comment: Приложение не вылетает. Отрабатывает DoinBackgrnd. прячется прогресс бар и просто чистый экран. Я поправил ответ добавил лог

Comment: Лучше текстом - скрин не все смогут увидеть, да и неудобно.

Comment: Парсер выдаёт ошибку не законченного элемента, подозреваю, что с сервера приходит что-то не то. Попробуйте прочитать поток в строку и вывести лог.

Comment: Как это правильно сделать?

Comment: В комментариях код превратится в кашу: `BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream(), "utf-8"));
             String line;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
     System.out.println(line);
    }` , надеюсь разберётесь.

Comment: Хотя бы выведите в лог `connection.getResponseCode()` перед парсингом - если не 200, то разбирайтесь с API сервера на предмет правильности запроса

Comment: поправил в шапку то что приходит

Comment: 05-10 16:12:00.436 31937-32030/com.roman.xml E/AsyncTask: 302
    START_TAG

Comment: Ну это явно не `xml` - наверное делаете запрос не правильно, смотрите документацию к API

Comment: Ну да, согласен, подсунул другой сайт заведомо рабочий, лог отдает 200 и вижу в логах всю структуру файла + заполняется листвью хотя null. Возможно дело в этой строчке , не совсем понимаю как тут передать Header/    Для идентификации API запросов необходимо передавать секретный ключ через
HTTP заголовок “X-AppId”. Например:

Comment: в любом случае спасибо, теперь я хотя бы понимаю что дело в ответе сервера.