# Следить за Log-ами приложения

Tags: java, android, логирование

**UPDATED**
Как правильно записывать логи в файл в приложении, что проверяют тестировщики?

Записывать логи нужно когда появлются какие то ошибки или выкинуло из приложения

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/797531/У-меня-просят-стектрейс-stack-trace-или-логкат-logcat-Что-это/797532#797532

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [У меня просят стектрейс (Stack Trace) или логкат (Logcat). Что это?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/797531/%d0%a3-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d1%8f%d1%82-%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b9%d1%81-stack-trace-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%82-logcat-%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%8d%d1%82%d0%be)

Comment: Нет это не то. Я имею ввиду если приложение тестируется не подключенное к Android Studio. Скажим тестится кем-то стороним человеком. И если у него выходит ошибка, чтобы эта ошибка записывалась в лог файл

Comment: Ну дык во всех стремных местах писать в логи (например, log4j в помощь).

Comment: @Abdugani_T как я понимаю, вопрос в том, когда тестировщики ловят баг, как им передать программисту лог ошибки, верно?

Comment: @iamtihonov Да всё верно

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Первый вариант, подключить устройство к компьютеру, у которого предварительно скачан `adb` и сохранить лог в файл после появления ошибки с помощью команды:

> adb logcat > logcat.txt

Второй вариант, если на устройстве есть `ROOT` использовать приложение из `GooglePlay` `CatLog` или `Log collector` и подобные.

Третий вариант использовать сервис который отправит сразу логи на сервер, которые можно смотреть в реальном времени, например `Hockey App` или
`Acra`.

Ещё вариант использовать библиотеку [Hyperion-Android](https://github.com/willowtreeapps/Hyperion-Android) и её модуль `'com.willowtreeapps.hyperion:hyperion-crash:0.9.24'`, которая после появления ошибки будет её отображать и использовать.

Comment: Есть ли вариант с кодом, чтобы при выявлении ошибки он записывал в файл?

Comment: Добавил ещё один вариант, на счет сохранения это вам нужно самому написать слушатель ошибок, например https://stackoverflow.com/a/16562770 и в нем я думаю записывать ошибку в файл.