# RunOnUiTread() вылетает приложение

Tags: android, c#, xamarin

Проблема с потоками. Пытаюсь изменить UI часть путем добавления сообщения к textView5. На этапе компиляции все нормально. Запускаю приложение, на эмуляторе в итоге видно что вылетает на этапе где я добавляю раскодированный текст к textView5. Не могу понять в чем моя ошибка.

```
using System;
using Android.App;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Support.V7.App;
using Android.Widget;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Threading;
using System.Text;
using Android.Support.Design.Widget;
using Android;

namespace App3
{
    [Activity(Label = "@string/app_name", Theme = "@style/AppTheme", MainLauncher = true)]
    public class MainActivity : Activity
    {
        TextInputEditText textInputEditText1, textInputEditText2, textInputEditText3;
        Button button1, button2, button3;
        static TextView textView3, textView5;
        static Socket socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(delegate () { Receiver(); }));
        static MainActivity mn;
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);
            button1 = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.button1);
            button2 = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.button2);
            button3 = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.button3);
            textInputEditText1 = FindViewById<TextInputEditText>(Resource.Id.textInputEditText1);
            textInputEditText2 = FindViewById<TextInputEditText>(Resource.Id.textInputEditText2);
            textInputEditText3 = FindViewById<TextInputEditText>(Resource.Id.textInputEditText3);
            textView3 = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textView3);
            textView5 = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textView5);
            button1.Click += Conn;
            button2.Click += Sender;
            button3.Click += Disconn;
        }
        public void Conn(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string ip_address = textInputEditText1.Text;
            int port = Convert.ToInt32(textInputEditText2.Text);
            socket.Connect(ip_address, port);
            if (socket.Connected)
            {
                textView3.Text = "Status: Connected";
                button3.Visibility = Android.Views.ViewStates.Visible;
                t.Start();
            }
            else textView3.Text = "Failed to connect to server";
        }
        public void Disconn(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            t.Abort();
            socket.Send(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes("_0xcAB2402"));
            Thread.Sleep(150);
            socket.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
            socket.Disconnect(true);
            button3.Visibility = Android.Views.ViewStates.Invisible;
        }
        public void Sender(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            byte[] msg = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(textInputEditText3.Text);
            socket.Send(msg, 0, msg.Length, 0);
        }
        public static void Receiver()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                byte[] buffer = new byte[128];
                socket.Receive(buffer);
                mn.RunOnUiThread(() => textView5.Append(Encoding.Unicode.GetString(buffer))); // На этом месте крашит
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Стектрейс ошибки покажите

Comment: public static void Receiver()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                try
                {
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[128];
                    socket.Receive(buffer);
                    mn.RunOnUiThread(() => textView5.Append(Encoding.Unicode.GetString(buffer)));
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    textView3.Text =  e.StackTrace;
                }
            }
        } Так?

Comment: Или подскажите как лучше вывести стектрейс

Comment: Найдите его в логах студии и добавьте в вопрос (править под вопросом). https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/797531/%D0%A3-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%8F%D1%82-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%81-stack-trace-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82-logcat-%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE

Comment: А если не пользуюсь эмулятором студии?

Comment: в любой IDE должен быть логкат, посмотрите для вашей

Comment: посмотрите возможное решение здесь: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44521573/widewine-drm-in-exoplayer-error там та же ошибка

Comment: То есть скорее всего проблемы с Encoding'ом?

Comment: А почему у вас TextView static?