# SQLite ошибка при добавление

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Нашел пример в интернете как работать с бд решил реализовать под свою задачу. Создал класс DBHelper:

```
     public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
       public  static final int DATABASE_VERSION=1;
       public  static final String  DATABASE_NAME="contactDb";
       public  static final String  TABLE_CONTACTS="contacts";

       public  static final String  KEY_ID="_id";//ид
       public  static final String  KEY_NAME="name";//название (гречка, молоко, мясо)
       public  static final String  KEY_SQUIRRELS =" Squirrels";//кол-во белка
       public  static final String  KEY_FAT ="Fat";//кол-во жиров
       public  static final String  KEY_CARBOHYDRATES ="Carbohydrates";//кол-во углеводы
       public  static final String  KEY_CALORIES ="Calories";//кол_во калорий


        public DBHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);


}

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("create table "+ TABLE_CONTACTS+"("+KEY_ID+"integer primary key,"+KEY_NAME+"text,"+
            KEY_SQUIRRELS +"integer,"+ KEY_FAT +"integer,"+ KEY_CARBOHYDRATES +"integer,"+ KEY_CALORIES +
            "integer"+")");//Если таблицы не существует то мы ее создаем
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("drop table if exists " + TABLE_CONTACTS);
        onCreate(db);//а тут обновляем таблицу

}
}
```

После чего пытаюсь по нажатию добавить, но он выдает ошибку

> E/SQLiteLog: (1) table contacts has no column named name
>   E/SQLiteDatabase: Error inserting name=Name Fat=2 Carbohydrates=3  Squirrels=1 Calories=4
>       android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table contacts has no column named name (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO contacts(name,Fat,Carbohydrates, Squirrels,Calories) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)
>           at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
>           at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:890)
>           at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:501)
>           at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
>           at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
>           at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
>           at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1546)
>           at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1417)
>           at com.example.testsqlite.MainActivity.onClick(MainActivity.java:53)
>           at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6294)
>           at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24770)
>           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)

в строке

```
 database.insert(DBHelper.TABLE_CONTACTS, null, contentValues);
```

Добавлял я таким образом

```
 contentValues.put(DBHelper.KEY_NAME, name);
              contentValues.put(DBHelper.KEY_SQUIRRELS,protein);
              contentValues.put(DBHelper.KEY_FAT, jir);
              contentValues.put(DBHelper.KEY_CARBOHYDRATES, ygli);
              contentValues.put(DBHelper.KEY_CALORIES, calorii);
```

Подскажите решение данной проблемы. Заранее спасибо

Comment: какую именно ошибку выдает?

Comment: @pavlofff  `at com.example.testsqlite.MainActivity.onClick(MainActivity.java:57)` а 57 строка это `database.insert(DBHelper.TABLE_CONTACTS, null, contentValues);`

Comment: добавьте [весь стектрейс](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/797531/177345) процесса, эта строка ни о чем не говорит

Comment: Ошибка говорит о том, что колонки "name" в таблице не существует. Вы добавляли эту колонку или изменяли ее имя после первого тестового запуска приложения?

Comment: @pavlofff нет это ошибка была при первом запуске `db.execSQL("create table "+ TABLE_CONTACTS+"("+KEY_ID+"integer primary key,"+KEY_NAME+"text,"+ KEY_SQUIRRELS +"text,"+ KEY_FAT +"text,"+ KEY_CARBOHYDRATES +"text,"+ KEY_CALORIES + "text"+")");` вроде тут она добавлена

Answer (score 0):

Ну решил вроде проблему. Из-за незнания правильного синтаксиса возникли ошибки. Что я сделал перепроверил строчку

```
db.execSQL("create table "+ TABLE_CONTACTS+"("+KEY_ID+" integer primary key,"+KEY_NAME+" text,"+ KEY_SQUIRRELS +" integer,"+ KEY_FAT +" integer,"+ KEY_CARBOHYDRATES +" integer,"+ KEY_CALORIES + " integer"+")");
```

Расставил пробелы перед integer и text. Хотя не думаю что в этом была ошибка. Плюс перед запуском поменял версию базы данных с 1 на 2. Щас все работает, только не хочет показывать данные по полю SQUIRRELS. Так что как-то так

Comment: Пробелы нужны, т.к. это строковые значения, без них имена столбцов сливаются с типом данных. Так что перепроверяй свои запросы.