# Приложение с WebView не запускается на устройствах ниже Android 7.0

Tags: android, webview, мобильная-разработка, android-webview

При добавлении виджета `WebView` приложение запускается на эмуляторах и устройствах 7+ версии андроид, на версиях ниже устанавливается, но не запускается.

> unfortunately app has stopped

Какие есть способы исправить это и запускать `WebView` на андроидах 4+ версии? Или может есть другие способы отображать веб-контент, при этом не сильно добавляя веса приложению?

Я его добавляю в приложение точно так же, как `ImageView`, к примеру:

```
public class Frag2 extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup viewGroup, Bundle savedInstanceState){
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_frag2, viewGroup, false); 
        WebView webView = (WebView)v.findViewById(R.id.webView); 
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()); 
        webView.loadUrl("google.com");
        return v;
```

Comment: Плюс вам за вот этот кусочек текста, остались еще адекватные люди на свете =) **при этом не сильно добавляя веса приложению**

Comment: `WebView` есть во всех версиях Андроида, проблема скорее в том, что вы используете какие-либо функции, которые доступны только с Андроид 7. Чтобы разобраться в проблеме нужны, как минимум логи ([У меня просят стектрейс (Stack Trace) или логкат (Logcat). Что это?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/797531)).

Comment: Посмотрите причины падения, комментарий выше от @woesss. Возможно приложение падает в другом месте, здесь нужно смотреть код не только всего фрагмента, но и класса активити.