# Не работает приложение Android после вставки самого обычного изображения

Tags: java, android, xml

Я вставляю изображение, делаю его на весь экран и после этого выходит, что у меня 0 ошибок, но в итоге приложения вылетает и даже не запускает его. Прошу, пожалуйста, помочь мне.

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/bg"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/bg" />
```

Comment: можете добавить ошибку из логов при вылете приложения?

Comment: используйте android:src вместо app:srcCompat. И картинку можно попробовать сделать меньше и или сделать её в разных размерах

Comment: Вообще выходит: Missing contentDescription attribute on Image

Comment: Несколько раз сталкивался с тем, что приложение вылетает с out of memory, при попытке установить большое фоновое изображение в ImageView напрямую через xml. Нужно либо попробовать оптимизировать само изображение, либо загружать его в ImageView в рантайме, используя, например Glide (ну или Picasso).

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/797531/У-меня-просят-стектрейс-stack-trace-или-логкат-logcat-Что-это