# Manifest. Android Studio. Проблема в манифесте

Tags: android, android-manifest

Знаю, что проблема с кодом в манифесте. Я новичок, поправьте меня пожалуйста.Буду особо признателен, если объясните в чем ошибка. Приложение вылетает при запуске

Класс MainActivity

```js
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void onClick(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MapsActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Логи[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.kldgid">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/logo"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@drawable/logo"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning">

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

        <activity
            android:name=".SplashScreenActivity"
            android:theme="@style/SplashScreen">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Какая проблема? Как вы поняли, что дело в манифесте? У вас есть какие-то логи какой-то ошибки?

Comment: В логе все чисто, понял что проблема в манифесте методом подбора (создал новый проект и вставлял файлы до момента пока приложение не начало вылетать)

Comment: возможно мне кажется, но в манифесте проблем нету, при вылете чаще всего в логах должно что-то быть, хоть что-то но есть всегда

Comment: Если у вас вылетает и нет логов ошибки - то у вас проблема - в манифесте ошибки не видно. Поищите получше логи падения. Попробуйте переустановить с нуля приложение - может у вас студия глючит с обновлением кода без пересборки.

Comment: В том то и дело, что я уже новый проект использую, студия глючить не может, винде 3 дня и сбоев никаких небыло. Сейчас попробую прикрепть логи

Comment: Сейчас понял, что туда видимо куда я смотрел (логи) неверно. Подскажите где мне их взять-то? :D

Comment: Xelloeuy, вкладка logcat в нижней части android Studio. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/797531/У-меня-просят-стектрейс-stack-trace-или-логкат-logcat-Что-это

Comment: Прикрепил картинку к посту, там логи

Comment: Xelloeuy, у тебя в манифесте неправильно прописан путь до MainActivity, судя по всему!

Comment: Откуда взять путь и как его прописать?

Comment: Приложи, пожалуйста, код MainActivity полностью. Если кода много - думаю, хватит верхних строк.

Comment: Приложил MainActivity

Comment: меня интересовала самая верхняя строка) (выше импортов)

Comment: package com.example.kldgid;

Comment: Извини, я невнимательно прочитал лог
проблема не с MainActivity, а с MapsActivity. Ее надо прописать в манифесте как минимум

Comment: Точно! Увидел, что не прописано! Момент..

Comment: Ура!! Заработало!! Большущее спасибо. Я тут первый раз и это мой первый вопрос. Как тут повысить вам "рейтинг" за помощь?

Comment: я сейчас напишу ответ, будет возможность пометить его правильным) Поздравляю с успехом!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема связана с отсутствием в манифесте MapsActivity

```
public void onClick(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MapsActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Данный код приводит к ошибке Unable to found explicit activity class.