# Проблема с подключением готовобой базы данных SQlite в android приложение

Tags: java, android, android-studio, sqlite, android-sqlite

Не могу понять почему не работает. Прочитал кучу информации и вроде все правильно. 
Основное что мне надо - это достать данные из таблиц(ы) и записать их в HashMap или ArrayList.

Подскажите что не правильно делаю

MainActiviti.java

```
package com.example.testdb;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {



    private DatabaseHelper mDBHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase mDb;
    private TextView textView;
    private ArrayList<String> name;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mDBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);

        try {
            mDBHelper.updateDataBase();
        } catch (IOException mIOException) {
            throw new Error("UnableToUpdateDatabase");
        }

        try {
            mDb = mDBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        } catch (SQLException mSQLException) {
            throw mSQLException;
        }
        textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);
        name = new ArrayList<String>();
        Cursor cursor = mDb.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM buildings", null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        while (!cursor.isAfterLast()){

            name.add(cursor.getString(3));
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }
        cursor.close();

        textView.setText(name.get(1));


        HashMap

    }
}
```

DBhelper.java

```
package com.example.testdb;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static String DB_NAME = "buildings.db";
    private static String DB_PATH = "";
    private static final int DB_VERSION = 1;

    private SQLiteDatabase mDataBase;
    private final Context mContext;
    private boolean mNeedUpdate = false;

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 17)
            DB_PATH = context.getApplicationInfo().dataDir + "/databases/";
        else
            DB_PATH = "/data/data/" + context.getPackageName() + "/databases/";
        this.mContext = context;

        copyDataBase();

        this.getReadableDatabase();
    }

    public void updateDataBase() throws IOException {
        if (mNeedUpdate) {
            File dbFile = new File(DB_PATH + DB_NAME);
            if (dbFile.exists())
                dbFile.delete();

            copyDataBase();

            mNeedUpdate = false;
        }
    }

    private boolean checkDataBase() {
        File dbFile = new File(DB_PATH + DB_NAME);
        return dbFile.exists();
    }

    private void copyDataBase() {
        if (!checkDataBase()) {
            this.getReadableDatabase();
            this.close();
            try {
                copyDBFile();
            } catch (IOException mIOException) {
                throw new Error("ErrorCopyingDataBase");
            }
        }
    }

    private void copyDBFile() throws IOException {
        InputStream mInput = mContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);
        OutputStream mOutput = new FileOutputStream(DB_PATH + DB_NAME);
        byte[] mBuffer = new byte[1024];
        int mLength;
        while ((mLength = mInput.read(mBuffer)) > 0)
            mOutput.write(mBuffer, 0, mLength);
        mOutput.flush();
        mOutput.close();
        mInput.close();
    }

    public boolean openDataBase() throws SQLException {
        mDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(DB_PATH + DB_NAME, null, SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY);
        return mDataBase != null;
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void close() {
        if (mDataBase != null)
            mDataBase.close();
        super.close();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        if (newVersion > oldVersion)
            mNeedUpdate = true;
    }
}
```

Выдает ошибку. Ругается когда пытаюсь из ArrayList достать значение и присвоет тексту. XML фаил базовый при создании, только добавил id для TextView. Подскажите, пожалуйста, где моя ошибка или что я не правильно делаю. Спасибо.

Comment: Где ошибка? Что за ошибка?

Comment: Приложите, пожалуйста, Logcat. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/797531/У-меня-просят-стектрейс-stack-trace-или-логкат-logcat-Что-это