# Валидный запрос wall.get (VKApi) на получение постов сообщества

Tags: java, vkontakte-api

Выполняю запрос в проекте на получение постов из группы Вконтакте при нажатии кнопки:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }

    private void response(){

        VKRequest request = VKApi.wall().get(VKParameters.from(VKApiConst.OWNER_ID,-79156872, VKApiConst.EXTENDED,1,VKApiConst.COUNT,1,VKApiConst.FIELDS,"text"));
        request.executeWithListener(new VKRequest.VKRequestListener() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(VKResponse response) {
                VKList<VKApiPost> posts = (VKList<VKApiPost>) response.parsedModel;
                VKApiPost post = posts.get(0);
                Log.d("Post: ", post.toString());
                String textpost = post.text;
                System.out.println(textpost);

                //super.onComplete(response);
            }
        });
    }

    public void OnClick(View view) {
        response();
    }
```

Код написан, ошибки не показывает, id группы определен... Приложение по нажатию кнопки "вылетает"....
Что не так???

Comment: Приложите лог ошибки https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/797531/У-меня-просят-стектрейс-stack-trace-или-логкат-logcat-Что-это/797532#797532

Comment: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: by.dream.vk_groups, PID: 2412
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
        at …
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Context.getPackageName()' on a null object reference
…
        at by.dream.vk_groups.MainActivity.response(MainActivity.java:26)
        at by.dream.vk_groups.MainActivity.OnClick(MainActivity.java:41)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)

Comment: Вроде как ссылается на несуществующий объект...

Comment: Как я понял. Или нет?