# Вылетает при нажатии на кнопку

Tags: java, android

Просто вылетает при нажатии на кнопку "8 class, хотя должен переходить на новое активити.
Контроллер в котором нажимается кнопка:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
 public Button sevenb, eightb, nineb, tenb, elevenb;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    sevenb = findViewById(R.id.button1);
    eightb = findViewById(R.id.button2);
    nineb = findViewById(R.id.button3);
    tenb = findViewById(R.id.button4);
    elevenb = findViewById(R.id.button5);
}
 public void seven(View view) {
     //setContentView(R.layout.seven);
     Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SevenControl.class);
     startActivity(intent);

 }
 public void eight(View view) {
     //setContentView(R.layout.eight);
     Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), EightController.class);
     startActivity(intent);

 }
 public void nine(View view) {
     System.out.println("--");
 }
 public void ten(View view) {
     System.out.println("--");
 }
 public void eleven(View view) {
     System.out.println("--");
 }
}
```

Контроллер активити "8 class"

```
public class EightController extends AppCompatActivity {

public Button b;
public Intent intent;
public TextView tv;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.eight);
    b=findViewById(R.id.button8);
    tv=findViewById(R.id.textView8);
    final Spinner spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner8);

    ArrayAdapter<?> adapter =
            ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.eightClass, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);


    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View itemSelected, int selectedItemPosition, long selectedId) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });
}



public void back8(View view) {

}
```

}

xml активити "8 class"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".EightController"
>

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner8"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="82dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:entries="@array/eightClass"
/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView8"
    android:layout_width="366dp"
    android:layout_height="508dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/spinner8" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button8"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:onClick="back8"
    android:text="@string/back"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/797531/%d0%a3-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d1%8f%d1%82-%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b9%d1%81-stack-trace-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%82-logcat-%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%8d%d1%82%d0%be/797532#797532

Comment: Без логов падения можно только гадать. Вот догадка - вы активити в манифесте не объявили. И раз уж у вас их уже 8 штук, то вам стоит задуматься о переходе на фрагменты.

Comment: Что такое переход на фрагменты

Comment: Да, я и вправду просто не добавил в манифест, спасибо