# Почему приложение не устанавливается на планшет?

Tags: android

Создала приложение. В начальных настройках устанавливала API 14: Android 4.0

На телефон с Android 9 устанавливается без проблем.

На компьютерный BlueStacks тоже без проблем.

А вот на планшет Nexus 7 (API 23: Android 6.0) не устанавливается. Без объяснения причины...

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В чем может быть причина?

Вот 
Manifest Sources

app main manifest (this file)
 Other Manifest Files (Included in merge, but did not contribute any elements) drawerlayout:1.0.0 manifest, interpolator:1.0.0 manifest, swiperefreshlayout:1.0.0 manifest, constraintlayout:1.1.3 manifest, viewpager:1.0.0 manifest, lifecycle-runtime:2.0.0 manifest, fragment:1.0.0 manifest, legacy-support-core-utils:1.0.0 manifest, loader:1.0.0 manifest, print:1.0.0 manifest, slidingpanelayout:1.0.0 manifest, vectordrawable-animated:1.0.0 manifest, vectordrawable:1.0.1 manifest, lifecycle-livedata:2.0.0 manifest, appcompat:1.0.2 manifest, lifecycle-livedata-core:2.0.0 manifest, asynclayoutinflater:1.0.0 manifest, coordinatorlayout:1.0.0 manifest, core:1.0.1 manifest, lifecycle-viewmodel:2.0.0 manifest, customview:1.0.0 manifest, versionedparcelable:1.0.0 manifest, localbroadcastmanager:1.0.0 manifest, legacy-support-core-ui:1.0.0 manifest, documentfile:1.0.0 manifest, cursoradapter:1.0.0 manifest, core-runtime:2.0.0 manifest

Comment: Сложно сказать. Возможно у вас в логах что-то можно увидеть?

Comment: А где эти логи можно посмотреть?

Comment: покажите mergedManifest

Comment: @AliceMagic [У меня просят стектрейс (Stack Trace) или логкат (Logcat). Что это?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/797531/11515)

Comment: @Style-7, не знаю что такое mergedManifest. Я чайник. Но, на всякий случай, добавила текст файла AndroidManifest.xml.

Comment: Внизу есть вкладочки `Text` и [`Merged Manifests`](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/manifest-merge#inspect_the_merged_manifest_and_find_conflicts) - там отображается итоговый манифест, который будет запакован в приложение и из каких зависимостей составлены его параметры

Comment: В теории проблема может быть в девайсе. Попробуйте на другой/аналогичный планшет поставить. Если будет ставиться - попробуйте планшет почистить как-то (может места не хватает) или вообще к заводским настройкам его сбросить

Comment: Ясно)) Добавила mergedManifest

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, такое тоже может быть? Вообще планшет уже старенький и чудит бывает. Я даже к компу его подключить не могу. АПК по домашней сети перекинула)

Comment: А эмулятор у меня вообще не работает. Т.к. ноут тоже старый и проц не поддерживает чего-то там)) Вот я и тестирую все только через BlueStacks))

Comment: Что угодно может быть - от нехватки места под установку до сбоев в системе. Когда проблема в самом приложении, то обычно выдаётся причина неудачи, либо ошибка вылазит уже после установки при запуске.

Comment: Значит, очень похоже, это планшетный косяк. Ладно, спасибо большое всем за помощь! Буду пробовать на других девайсах.

Comment: Ещё может не устанавливаться дебажная/неподписанная версия, если на устройстве не включёны режим отладки и/или установка из сторонних источников.

Comment: апк - подписанный релиз

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте установить из командной строки через adb. В таком случае обычно пишется конкретная ошибка.

```
adb install путь_к_.apk
```

Comment: Не знаю пока, что такое adb, но попробую разобраться. Спасибо!