# Безошибочный вылет приложения Судоку Android studio. В чём может быть причина?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Пытаюсь написать своё первое приложение на Android Studio. И так сложилось что пришлось делать Судоку, для проекта. Но вот беда. Сделать, вроде сделал. Но приложения вылетает без каких либо ошибок. Не могли бы вы помочь мне в решении этой проблемы.
Файл MainActivity:

```
package com.example.sudoku408;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.GridView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private GridView mGridView;
    private Button b1,b2,b3,b4,b5,b6,b7,b8,b9;
    private String selectedButton = "n1";
    private Game mGame;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mGame = new Game(this);
        getUIItems();

        mGridView.setNumColumns(9);
        mGridView.setEnabled(true);
        mGridView.setAdapter(mGame);

        mGridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                mGame.setNumber(position, selectedButton);
            }
        });
    }

    private void getUIItems() {
        mGridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.field);

        b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1);
        b2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn2);
        b3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn3);
        b4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn4);
        b5 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn5);
        b6 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn6);
        b7 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn7);
        b8 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn8);
        b9 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn9);
    }
    public void setOnItemClickListener() {
        b1.setOnClickListener(this);
        b2.setOnClickListener(this);
        b3.setOnClickListener(this);
        b4.setOnClickListener(this);
        b5.setOnClickListener(this);
        b6.setOnClickListener(this);
        b7.setOnClickListener(this);
        b8.setOnClickListener(this);
        b9.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view){
        switch (view.getId()){
            case R.id.btn1: selectedButton = "n1";
                break;
            case R.id.btn2: selectedButton = "n2";
                break;
            case R.id.btn3: selectedButton = "n3";
                break;
            case R.id.btn4: selectedButton = "n4";
                break;
            case R.id.btn5: selectedButton = "n5";
                break;
            case R.id.btn6: selectedButton = "n6";
                break;
            case R.id.btn7: selectedButton = "n7";
                break;
            case R.id.btn8: selectedButton = "n8";
                break;
            case R.id.btn9: selectedButton = "n9";
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Файл AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.sudoku408">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Sudoku408">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Файл Game.java

```
package com.example.sudoku408;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

class Game  extends BaseAdapter  {

    private Context mContext;
    private final Integer mRows = 9, mCols = 9;
    private int numberArray[][] = new int[mRows][mCols];

    private Resources mRes;
    private ArrayList<String> arrPict;
    int UnblockPosition[] = new int[mRows*mCols];
    int helperArray[][];

    public Game(Context mContext){
        this.mContext = mContext;
        arrPict = new ArrayList<>(mCols*mRows);
        mRes = mContext.getResources();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mRows*mCols;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView imageView;

        if (view == null){
            imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
        } else {
            imageView = (ImageView) view;
        }

        Integer drawableId = mRes.getIdentifier(arrPict.get(position), "drawable", mContext.getPackageName());
        imageView.setImageResource(drawableId);

        return imageView;
    }

    private void createField(){
        initArray();

        for (int i = 0; i < mRows; i++){
            for (int j = 0; j < mCols; j++) {
                arrPict.add("n" + numberArray[i][j]);
            }
        }
        helperArray = numberArray;
    }
    public int getRow(int position){
        int row = 1;
        if (position<=8){
            return 0;
        }else {
            while(position>=0 && position <9) {
                row++;
            }
            while(position>=9){
                position = position - 9;
                row++;
            }
            return  row-1;
        }
    }
    public int getCell(int position){
        if (position<=8){
            return position;
        }else {
            return position % 9;
        }
    }
    private void initArray(){
        for (int i = 0; i < mRows; i++){
            for (int j = 0; j < mCols; j++) {
                numberArray[i][j] = j+1;
            }
        }
    }
    public void setNumber(int position, String selectedButton){
        for (int i = 0; i < UnblockPosition.length; i++){
            if (UnblockPosition[i] == position){
                arrPict.set(position, selectedButton);
                helperArray[getRow(position)][getCell(position)] = Integer.parseInt(selectedButton.split("n")[1]);
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Файл activity_main:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/field"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="400dp"
        android:background="@drawable/sudoku"
        android:onClick="onClick"></GridView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:background="#c5718079"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn1"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:text="1"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"></Button>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn2"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:text="2"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"></Button>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn3"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:text="3"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"></Button>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn4"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:text="4"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"></Button>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn5"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:text="5"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"></Button>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn6"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:text="6"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"></Button>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn7"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:text="7"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"></Button>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn8"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:text="8"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"></Button>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn9"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:text="9"></Button>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

P.S android:background="@drawable/sudoku" - sudoku это просто картинка с клетками судоку
n1, n2, n3, n4, n5, n6, n7, n8, n9 - это картинки с цифрами для заполнения судоку.

Comment: Посмотрите logcat, там должна выводиться ошибка

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/797531/177345