# Listview не выводит поля из массива в Strings.xml

Tags: java, android

в Strings.xml содержится массив данных, которые нужно вывести в listview с названием creatorList.
настройки ListView:

```
<ListView
        android:id="@+id/creatorList"
        android:textColor="#1031D3"
        android:layout_width="407dp"
        android:layout_height="635dp"

        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/version"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/Creator" />
```

код в MainActivity.jar
ListView creatorList;

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    buttonCreator = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonCreator);
    buttonCreator.setOnClickListener(this);

    ListView creatorList = findViewById(R.id.creatorList);
    String[] creator = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.creator);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, creator);
    creatorList.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

данный ListView нужно привязать к Activity - Activity_creator.xml

Activiti_Main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonStart"
        android:layout_width="143dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:text="Start"
        app:backgroundTint="#1031D3"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.932" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonCreator"
        android:layout_width="277dp"
        android:layout_height="43dp"
        android:text="Creator"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/buttonStart"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.059"
        app:backgroundTint="#1031D3"

        />




</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Активити на котором находится listview:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Creator">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Creator"
        android:layout_width="252dp"
        android:layout_height="39dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Creator"
        android:textColor="#1031D3"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"


        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.497"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.039"

        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/version"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="version 0.0.2"
        android:textColor="#1031D3"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"

         />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/creatorList"
        android:textColor="#1031D3"
        android:layout_width="407dp"
        android:layout_height="635dp"

        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/version"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/Creator" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: С текущим кодом проблем нет, покажите весь activity_main.xml ([отредактируйте](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1313836/edit) вопрос), может что с ConstraintLayout не так.

Comment: Еще нужно уточнение по поводу "Listview не выводит поля". Что вы видите на экране? Есть ли при этом ошибки в [logcat](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/797531)? Добавьте эту информацию в вопрос.

Answer (score 2):

Ошибка заключается в том, что вы делаете `findViewById(R.id.creatorList)` в классе `MainActivity`.

Класс `MainActivity` соответствует разметке `activity_main.xml`, но в нем у вас нет вьюх с id `creatorList`.

ListView находится в другой активити, в ней и делайте `findViewById(R.id.creatorList)`.