# Android-разработка (проблема с эмулятором)

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Я пытаюсь запустить свое первое приложение в Android studio, но вместо проекта “hello world” в эмуляторе запускается рабочий стол телефона( а на нем есть иконка Гугл и мессенджер). Что нудно сделать, чтобы запустилась программа?

Comment: Возможных причин может быть несколько сотен, не получится даже в ответе все перечислить. Надо как-то локализовать проблему. Возможно, у вас в логах что-то есть - т.е. приложение просто падает?

Comment: Посмотрите логи в [logcat](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/797531) на наличие ошибок.

Comment: Надо просто открыть список приложений, найти в нем иконку своего приложения и ткнуть. Не пробовали?

Answer (score 0):

В Android Studio рядом к кнопкой запуска должен быть выбор где запускать приложение. Возможно у тебя там что-то другое стоит. Проверь. Надо чтобы был выбран твой эмулятор.