# Как правильно передать ArrayList в другое activity

Tags: android, kotlin, android-parcelable

У меня есть следующие класс данных:

```
data class LegendWrapper(
    val data: List<PlayerPerformance>? = emptyList()

)
data class PlayerPerformance(val name: String, val value: Int, val key: String)

data class TestList(val name: String, val data: LegendWrapper)
```

Затем я заполняю список из Мар

```
for((key, value ) in data.legends.all){
recList.add(TestList(key, value))
}
```

Затем при нажатии на имя в RecyclerView я хочу получить данные в другой активити.
Я попытался сделать как на примере ниже, но по итогу получаю данные в виде строки с которыми просто невозможно правильно работать, пробовал через `putParcelableArrayListExtra` натыкаюсь на исключения несоответсвия типов, как правильно осуществить передачу ArrayList в другую активити ?

```
 heroesAdapt = HeroesRecyclerAdapter(this, recList){
   testList -> val heroesStatsActivity = Intent(this,HeroesStatsActivity::class.java)
   heroesStatsActivity.putExtra("nicknameHeroes", testList.name)
   heroesStatsActivity.putExtra("data", testList.data.toString())
   startActivity(heroesStatsActivity)
}
```

Немного погуглил нашел такой вариант, но он тоже не работает `heroesStatsActivity.putExtra("data", testList)`
так передаю. А получить вот так `val test = intent.extras?.getSerializable("data") as TestList` При том что сам класс данных унаследовал от **Serializable** `data class TestList(val name: String, val data: LegendWrapper) : Serializable` При выборе имени со списка вот такая ошибка

> ```
> 2021-08-22 17:33:12.426 4950-4950/com.example.studyactivitylifecyl
> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>     Process: com.example.studyactivitylifecyl, PID: 4950
>     java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcelable encountered IOException writing serializable object (name =
> com.example.studyactivitylifecyl.Model.TestList)
>         at android.os.Parcel.writeSerializable(Parcel.java:2113)
>         at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1883)
>         at android.os.Parcel.writeArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:975)
>         at android.os.BaseBundle.writeToParcelInner(BaseBundle.java:1620)
>         at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1303)
>         at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:1044)
>         at android.content.Intent.writeToParcel(Intent.java:10855)
>         at android.app.IActivityTaskManager$Stub$Proxy.startActivity(IActivityTaskManager.java:3668)
>         at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1723)
>         at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:5314)
>         at androidx.activity.ComponentActivity.startActivityForResult(ComponentActivity.java:597)
>         at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:5272)
>         at androidx.activity.ComponentActivity.startActivityForResult(ComponentActivity.java:583)
>         at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:5658)
>         at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:5611)
>         at com.example.studyactivitylifecyl.HeroesActivity$onCreate$1.invoke(HeroesActivity.kt:45)
>         at com.example.studyactivitylifecyl.HeroesActivity$onCreate$1.invoke(HeroesActivity.kt:40)
>         at com.example.studyactivitylifecyl.Adapters.HeroesRecyclerAdapter$Holder.bindHeroes$lambda-0(HeroesRecyclerAdapter.kt:25)
>         at com.example.studyactivitylifecyl.Adapters.HeroesRecyclerAdapter$Holder.lambda$m9Ppe9nWqwgcbjiXqOm_6-7XHbo(Unknown
> Source:0)
>         at com.example.studyactivitylifecyl.Adapters.-$$Lambda$HeroesRecyclerAdapter$Holder$m9Ppe9nWqwgcbjiXqOm_6-7XHbo.onClick(Unknown
> Source:4)
>         at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7448)
>         at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7425)
>         at android.view.View.access$3600(View.java:810)
>         at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:28305)
>         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
>         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
>         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
>         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>         at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
>         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
>      Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: com.example.studyactivitylifecyl.Model.LegendWrapper
>         at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1240)
>         at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1604)
>         at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1565)
>         at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1488)
>         at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1234)
>         at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:354)
>         at android.os.Parcel.writeSerializable(Parcel.java:2108)
>         at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1883) 
>         at android.os.Parcel.writeArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:975) 
>         at android.os.BaseBundle.writeToParcelInner(BaseBundle.java:1620) 
>         at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1303) 
>         at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:1044) 
>         at android.content.Intent.writeToParcel(Intent.java:10855) 
>         at android.app.IActivityTaskManager$Stub$Proxy.startActivity(IActivityTaskManager.java:3668) 
>         at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1723) 
>         at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:5314) 
>         at androidx.activity.ComponentActivity.startActivityForResult(ComponentActivity.java:597) 
>         at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:5272) 
>         at androidx.activity.ComponentActivity.startActivityForResult(ComponentActivity.java:583) 
>         at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:5658) 
>         at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:5611) 
>         at com.example.studyactivitylifecyl.HeroesActivity$onCreate$1.invoke(HeroesActivity.kt:45) 
>         at com.example.studyactivitylifecyl.HeroesActivity$onCreate$1.invoke(HeroesActivity.kt:40) 
>         at com.example.studyactivitylifecyl.Adapters.HeroesRecyclerAdapter$Holder.bindHeroes$lambda-0(HeroesRecyclerAdapter.kt:25) 
>         at com.example.studyactivitylifecyl.Adapters.HeroesRecyclerAdapter$Holder.lambda$m9Ppe9nWqwgcbjiXqOm_6-7XHbo(Unknown
> Source:0) 
>         at com.example.studyactivitylifecyl.Adapters.-$$Lambda$HeroesRecyclerAdapter$Holder$m9Ppe9nWqwgcbjiXqOm_6-7XHbo.onClick(Unknown
> Source:4) 
>         at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7448) 
>         at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7425) 
>         at android.view.View.access$3600(View.java:810) 
>         at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:28305) 
>         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938) 
>         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
>         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223) 
>         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656) 
>         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>         at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592) 
>         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
> ```

Переделал немного код.

```
@Parcelize
data class LegendWrapper(
    val data: List<PlayerPerformance>? = emptyList()

): Parcelable

@Parcelize
data class PlayerPerformance(val name: String, val value: Int, val key: String): Parcelable

@Parcelize
data class TestList(val name: String, val data: LegendWrapper) : Parcelable
```

Далее пытаюсь передать

```
heroesStatsActivity.putParcelableArrayListExtra("data", testList)
```

но получаю ошибку

> Type mismatch. Required: ArrayList<out Parcelable!>? Found: TestList

Если же просто написать putExtra

```
heroesStatsActivity.putExtra("data", testList)
```

Тогда во второй активити ошибка

```
val test = intent?.extras?.getParcelable("data")
```

> Not enough information to infer type variable T

Comment: "натыкаюсь на исключения несоответствия типов" -- [отредактируйте](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1320332/edit) вопрос, напишите конкретную ошибку, с которой вы столкнулись. Использование `putParcelableArrayListExtra` это ок.

Comment: Приведите, пожалуйста, полный [стектрейс](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/797531/) ошибки с указанием номера строчки, где происходит ошибка.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В Андроиде все данные между разными активити передаются в специальном контейнере [Parcel](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcel). В этот контейнер можно складывать только определнные типы данных. Один из таких типов — `Parcelable`.

Вы используете `putParcelableArrayListExtra`, все верно, только необходимо, чтобы `TestList` имплементировал интерфейс [Parcelable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable). Чтобы не писать реализацию Parcelable вручную, можно воспользоваться плагином [kotlin-parcelize](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/parcelize).

Приведу пример, как это сделать с помощью kotlin-parcelize:

1. Помечаем аннотацией `@Parcelize` все классы, которые будут передаваться и имплементируем интерфейс `Parcelable`:

   ```
   @Parcelize
   class MyExtra(...) : Parcelable
   ```
2. В Активити «A» кладем объект `myExtra` в интент и стартуем Активити «Б»:

   ```kotlin
   val myExtra: MyExtra = ...
   startActivity(
       Intent(this, ActivityБ::class.java)
           .putExtra("com.example.my_extra", myExtra)
   )
   ```
3. В Активити «Б» вытаскиваем данный объект из интента:

   ```kotlin
   val myExtra = intent.getParcelableExtra<MyExtra>("com.example.my_extra")
   ```

Comment: Я думал можно проще, немного погуглил нашел такой вариант, но он тоже не работает ```heroesStatsActivity.putExtra("data", testList)``` так передаю. А получить вот так  ```val test = intent.extras?.getSerializable("data") as TestList``` При том что сам класс данных унаследовал от Serializable ```data class TestList(val name: String, val data: LegendWrapper) : Serializable``` При выборе имени со списка вот такая ошибка *Parcelable encountered IOException writing serializable object (name = com.example.studyactivitylifecyl.Model.TestList)*

Comment: Parcelable более производительный, чем Serializable, но разницу вы вряд ли почувствуете. Да, смысл тот же. Передавать между активити можно Parcelable, Serializable и еще некоторый набор базовых типов.

Comment: Тексты ошибок прикладывайте в сам вопрос.

Comment: обновил, Я правильно понимаю что не получится просто унаследовать Serializable и получить свои данные в другой активити ?

Comment: Обновил ответ, добавил пример использования kotlin-parcelize.

Comment: всё заработало, большое спасибо

Comment: Кстати можно ещё через "kotlin-android-extensions" ибо когда этот плагин подключен то "kotlin-parcelize" конфликтует между собой

Comment: Плагин `kotlin-android-extensions` уже [устарел](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65179275/the-kotlin-android-extensions-gradle-plugin-is-deprecated), вместо него теперь нужно использовать `kotlin-parcelize`. А если вы пользовались kotlin-synthetic, то теперь вместо него можно использовать [view-binding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding/migration).

Comment: понял, огромное вам спасибо

Comment: Если у вас уже подключен `kotlin-android-extensions` и вы пока хотите еще какое-то время на нем посидеть, то `kotlin-parcelize` можно пока не подключать. Но в дальнейшем нужно переходить на `kotlin-parcelize` плагин.

Comment: Перейду прям сейчас. Ещё раз спасибо