# При запуске класса приложение выбивает

Tags: java, android, android-manifest

класс выбивающий приложение:

```
public class Levels extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.levelsection);

        Window w = getWindow();
        w.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        Button buttonBack = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonBack);
        buttonBack.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                try {
                    Intent intent= new Intent(Levels.this,MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);finish();
                }catch (Exception e){

                }
            }
        });

        TextView textLevelSection = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        textLevelSection.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                try {
                    Intent intent= new Intent(Levels.this,GameLevels.class);
                    startActivity(intent);finish();
                }catch (Exception e){

                }
            }
        });

        TextView textLevelSection2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        textLevelSection2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                try {
                    Intent intent= new Intent(Levels.this,GameLevels.class);
                    startActivity(intent);finish();
                }catch (Exception e){

                }
            }
        });

        TextView textLevelSection3 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        textLevelSection3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                try {
                    Intent intent= new Intent(Levels.this,GameLevels.class);
                    startActivity(intent);finish();
                }catch (Exception e){

                }
            }
        });

        TextView textLevelSection4 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView4);
        textLevelSection4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                try {
                    Intent intent= new Intent(Levels.this,GameLevels.class);
                    startActivity(intent);finish();
                }catch (Exception e){

                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

главный класс:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button buttonStart = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonStart);
        buttonStart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                try {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Levels.class);
                    startActivity(intent);finish();
                }catch (Exception e){

                }
            }
        });

        Window w = getWindow();
        w.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="yaroslav.firstapp.game">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Game">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Levels"
            android:exported="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".GameLevels"
            android:exported="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Level1"
            android:exported="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Level2"
            android:exported="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Level3"
            android:exported="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".Level4"
            android:exported="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>


</manifest>
```

Logcat:

> 2022-02-02 19:29:58.722 23636-23636/yaroslav.firstapp.game
> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> Process: yaroslav.firstapp.game, PID: 23636
> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{yaroslav.firstapp.game/yaroslav.firstapp.game.Levels}:
> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
> android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)'
> on a null object reference
> at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2778)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
> at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
> at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
> android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)'
> on a null object reference
> at yaroslav.firstapp.game.Levels.onCreate(Levels.java:23)
> at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7009)
> at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7000)
> at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1214)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2731)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856) 
> at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
> at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589) 
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494) 
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
> at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438) 
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)

строка с ошибкой:

```
    Window w = getWindow();
    w.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    Button buttonBack = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonBack);
!!!!buttonBack.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            try {
                Intent intent= new Intent(Levels.this,MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);finish();
            }catch (Exception e){
        
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: В вкладке LogCat будет причина падения

Comment: в каком классе?

Comment: это в IDE внизу есть вкладка, не в классе

Comment: `android:exported="true"` и блоки `<intent-filter>` не нужны активностям, которые вы запускаете сами из своего же приложения

Comment: activity подчеркивает красным

Comment: Блок - это открывающий тег `<intent-filter>`, закрывающий `</intent-filter>` и всё что между ними

Comment: мне нужно удалить android:exported="true" и <intent-filter> в каждой activity ?

Comment: Кроме главной. Если продолжит падать, прочтите это: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/797531/11515 и добавьте лог в вопрос

Comment: я сделал то что посоветовали по ссылке,что не так?

Comment: Судя по логу - в строке `Button buttonBack = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonBack);` вы в итоге записываете null в переменную buttonBack. Скорее всего вы опечатались в ID вашей кнопки. Или в разметке или в коде.

Comment: Спасибо большое! заплутался с id