# Ошибка создания файла: java.io.IOException: Read-only file system

Tags: java, android, listview

Доброе время суток: я решил изучить сохранение и чтение файлов, но по не известным(для меня) причинам приложение вылетает. Гугл мало чего показал, хотел бы от вас получить ответ, совет или такого рода фикса прилложения. Мне нужно, что бы при нажатии на список считывался файл, если в файле есть то слово, то выводиться Toast, если же нету, то это слово сохраняеться в файле

```java
public class ShopNew extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "Shop";
    private ListView listView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_shop_new);
       listView = findViewById(R.id.listView);
       ArrayList<String> arrayList=new ArrayList<>();

       arrayList.add("Абрикос");
       arrayList.add("Апельсин");

       ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.list_white_text, arrayList);
       listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

        try {
            //создаём файл
            File file = new File("list.txt");
            if(!file.exists())
                file.createNewFile();
            file.createNewFile();
        }catch (IOException e){
            Log.e(TAG, "Ошибка создания файла"+e);
        }

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
                switch (position){
                    case 0:
                        //создаём шнягу, которая считывает сторчки в файле
                        BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
                        try {
                            //создаём файл
                            File file = new File("list.txt");
                            //если файл существует, создаём его
                            if(!file.exists()) {
                                file.createNewFile();
                            }
                            //говорим шняге о названии файла, которая считвает
                            bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("list.txt"));
                            String line;
                            //переменная, которая записывает данные
                            PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(file);
                            //В переменную line мы записываем новую строку котораю мы считываем с файла
                            //если такая новая строка будет пустая (null) - мы выйдем с цикла
                            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine())!=null) {
                                //если в файле сущестует значение
                                if (printWriter.equals("апельсин")) {
                                    Toast.makeText(ShopNew.this, "У вас есть этот фрукт", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                                //если нет, записываем
                                else {
                                    printWriter.println("апельсин");
                                    printWriter.close();
                                    file.createNewFile();
                                }
                            }
                        }catch (IOException e){
                            Log.e(TAG, "Ошибка создания файла: "+e);
                        }
                        //закрываем файл. Испоьзуем finally, так как bufferReader не в try-catch
                        finally {
                            try {
                                bufferedReader.close();
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                   break;
                }
            }
        });
    }

}
```

в Logcat-e я отфильтровал список и при нажимании на список получил это:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Так же вот ошибка с закрытием чтения файла(наверное потому что нельзя создать)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
ошибок типа caused by, только сие чудо(с facebook.katana... Почему оно тут - не знаю)[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Добавьте [stacktrace](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/797531) ошибки в вопрос.

Comment: @Vadik, добавил

Comment: Вы неправильно логгируете ошибки, из-за этого очень сложно их анализировать в случае возникновения. Нужно так: `Log.e(TAG, "Ошибка создания файла", e);`. Третьим аргументом передавайте объект `e`, тогда стектрейс ошибки будет распечатан в logcat. Вы приложили стектрейс ошибки от приложения фейсбук.

Comment: Когда делаете `+ e`, то теряется вся важная информация об ошибке. И в logcat видна только базовая информация об ошибке, а не весь стектрейс.

Comment: Кроме этого, текстовую информацию лучше прикладывать в виде текста, чтобы ее можно было легко копировать и пользоваться поиском по тексту.

Comment: @Vadik, смешно в том, что Фейсбука даже в помине не было в моём приложении... Откуда Фейсбук явился?

Comment: Logcat может показывать все логи с устройства, если не задан фильтр по конкретному приложению. Если мой [ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1444572) вам помог исправить ошибку, то вы можете засчитать его как правильный.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Когда вы пишете `new File("list.txt")`, вы создаете файл в корне вашей файловой системы. Там создавать файлы запрещено, это приводит к ошибке:

```
java.io.IOException: Read-only file system
```

Файлы в Андроид можно создавать в директорях [`filesDir`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context#getFilesDir()) или [`cacheDir`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context#getCacheDir()), поэтому при создании объекта `File`, передайте первым аргументом соответствующую директорию. Например, так:

```java
File file = new File(getFilesDir(), "list.txt");
```

Подробнее о способах хранения данных есть в [официальной документации](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage).

Comment: Увы всё равно вылетает, но ошибку с системным файлом исправили

Comment: Если у вас уже другая ошибка, создайте новый вопрос и укажите детальный текст ошибки вместе со стектрейсом.

Answer (score 0):

Если у вас в каждой строке одно слово (например: апельсин), то можно делать как вы и использовать 'equals', вы в цикле 'while' перебираете каждую строчку и она записывается в 'line' и потом надо сверять эту строчку (если там одно слово) с искомым словом

```
while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) 
{
                //ИСПРАВЛЕНО вместо printWriter ставим line
                if (line.equals("апельсин")) 
                 {
                  Toast.makeText( "У вас есть этот фрукт", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                 }
                                //если нет, записываем
                  else {
//поправка от АСТРОНОМа вы проверяете каждую строчку и если в этой строчке нет слова 
//то он ее запишет, следовательно если у вас 5 строчек и нет ни в одном АПЕЛЬСИНа то он запишет вам в файл 5 раз слово АПЕЛЬСИН 
//ниже приведенная часть кода бесполезна, она будет полезна только если у вас одно слово в файле
                  printWriter.println("апельсин");
                  printWriter.close();
                        }
    }
```

Если у вас в строчке целое предложение и вы желаете узнать есть ли в этой строчке слово АПЕЛЬСИН, то тогда лучше применить этот код

```
 while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                String probel = " "; // знак разделитель между словами
                String[] beer = line.split(probel); //разделение, beer содержит массив всех слов в строчке (line)
                for(i=0;i<=beer.length;i++)
                 {
                    if(beer[i].equals("апельсин"))
                       {
                        System.out.println("у вас есть апельсин")
                        //или вывести через Toast
                        }
                 }
            }
```

Если вам надо записать слово "апельсин" когда его нет в файле, и вы используете 2-ой код, то можно сделать счетчик, если в файле нет слова АПЕЛЬСИН, то мы записываем АПЕЛЬСИН в файл, если есть хотя бы одно то не пишем.

```
int score =0;

 while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                String probel = " "; // знак разделитель между словами
                String[] beer = line.split(probel); //разделение, beer содержит массив всех слов в строчке (line)
                for(i=0;i<=beer.length;i++)
                 {
                    if(beer[i].equals("апельсин"))
                       {
                        System.out.println("у вас есть апельсин")
                         score++;
                        //или вывести через Toast
                        }
                 }
            }

            if(score=0)
            {
             bufferedReader.write("апельсин");
             bufferedReader.flush();
            }
```

Дополнительную информацию можете посмотреть [здесь](https://metanit.com/java/tutorial/6.8.php)

Возможно я допустил где-то ошибки, если так то пишите в комментарии.

Comment: У автора вопроса приложение падает из-за ошибки "Ошибка создания файла: java.io.IOException: Read-only file system", в вашем ответе не содержится решения этой проблемы.