# Не запускается Telegram bot на Java через IDEA

Tags: java, telegram-bot, intellij-idea, maven

Ошибка: **java: cannot access java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture
class file for java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture not found**

Подключил библиотеку с помощью Maven.
Вот код TelegramBotsApi для запуска бота:

```
import org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.TelegramBotsApi;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.exceptions.TelegramApiException;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.updatesreceivers.DefaultBotSession;

public class Main {
    public static void main (String [] args) {
        try {
            TelegramBotsApi botsApi = new TelegramBotsApi(DefaultBotSession.class);
            botsApi.registerBot(new telegaBot());
        } catch (TelegramApiException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

А вот код самого бота:

```
import org.telegram.telegrambots.bots.TelegramLongPollingBot;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.api.objects.Update;

public class telegaBot extends TelegramLongPollingBot {
    @Override
    public String getBotUsername() {
        return "bot_name";
    }

    @Override
    public String getBotToken() {
        return "token";
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpdateReceived(Update update) {
    }
}
```

Вот версии Java,Maven и IDEA
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

2. Попытка сборки командой mvn clean build
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
3. Содержимое pom.xml

   4.0.0

   ```
    <groupId>org.telegram</groupId>
    <artifactId>telegrambots</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>6</source>
                    <target>6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.telegram</groupId>
            <artifactId>telegrambots</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
   ```

Comment: 1. Приложите полный стектрейс ошибки в вопрос. 2. Попробуйте собрать проект командой `mvn clean build` (предварительно перейдите в директорию с вашим проектом с помощью команды `cd путь/до/проекта`), будет такая же ошибка?

Comment: @Vadik стектрейс и изображение попытки сборки приложил

Comment: 1. Это не [стектрейс](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/797531). 2. Команду запускайте из директории проекта, т. е. там, где находится `pom.xml`, т. е. из директории `Test3` (а у вас текущая директория это `Test3/src/main/java`, в ней нет `pom.xml`, поэтому сборка сразу падает). 3. Приложите содержимое вашего `pom.xml`.

Comment: @Vadik запустил команду из директории, результат выше. Сейчас пробую разобраться со стектресом, извините за медлительность. В Maven с помощью команды -e также можно получить стектрейс, он будет аналогичен полученному в IDEA?

Comment: @Vadik содержимое pom.xml приложил

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Скорее всего с помощью старой java пытаетесь запустить.
Если запускаете через IDE проверьте с помощью какой версии java IDE пытаеться запустить. Нужна java 8 или выше версии

IDE -> ctrl+alt+shift+s -> SDK [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В pom.xml поменяйте 6 java на 19(или на 11 как на скриншоте настройка проекта)

```
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
             <configuration>
                 <source>19</source>
                 <target>19</target>
             </configuration>
```

Comment: использую JDK19 - ошибка та же

Comment: В pom.xml поменяйте 6 java на 19