# Не работает код при нажатии на кнопку добавить во всплывающем окне

Tags: android, всплывающее-окно

```
public void SignUp(View view) {

        AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
        dialog.setTitle("Зарегистрироваться")
                .setMessage("Введите все данные для регистрации")
                .setCancelable(false);

        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
        View registerWindow = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_second, null);
        dialog.setView(registerWindow);

        dialog.setNegativeButton("Отменить", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                dialogInterface.cancel();
            }
        });

        dialog.setPositiveButton("Добавить", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int which) {
                EditText email = findViewById(R.id.email_field);
                EditText pass = findViewById(R.id.password);
                EditText name = findViewById(R.id.name);
                EditText numb = findViewById(R.id.number);


                User newUser = new User();
                newUser.setId(database.getKey());
                newUser.setEmail(email.getText().toString());
                newUser.setPass(pass.getText().toString());
                newUser.setName(name.getText().toString());
                newUser.setNumb(numb.getText().toString());
                database.push().setValue(newUser);

                }
        });
        dialog.show();
```

Android Java, Вылетает из программы без ошибки при нажатии на кнопку добавить, если установить тот же код к другой обычной кнопке, то он срабатывает без проблем. Как я понимаю проблема именно в диалоговом окне

Comment: Пожалуйста, сформулируйте вопрос точнее. Если код не работает, то укажите прямо в вопросе, что происходит, есть ли в логах ошибка, вылетает ли приложение с ошибкой, если да, то приложите текст ошибки и полный стектрейс. Кроме этого, укажите метку языка программирования в вашем вопросе. Отредактировать вопрос можно, нажав на кнопку [править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1484951/edit) под вопросом.

Comment: *Вылетает из программы без ошибки* - врёте, без ошибок программы вообще не вылетают, ищите сообщение об ошибке в Logcat ([У меня просят стектрейс (Stack Trace) или логкат (Logcat). Что это?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/797531/11515)).

Comment: Как вызвать сервис Firbase auth в этом коде ?

Answer (score 1):

Я так понимаю поля ввода располагаются в самом диалоге.
Тогда и искать их нужно в диалоге, вызывая его метод `findViewById()`, а не одноимённый метод активити, потому что в активити этих полей нет.

```java
        dialog.setPositiveButton("Добавить", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int which) {
                Dialog dialog = (Dialog) dialogInterface;
                EditText email = dialog.findViewById(R.id.email_field);
                EditText pass = dialog.findViewById(R.id.password);
                EditText name = dialog.findViewById(R.id.name);
                EditText numb = dialog.findViewById(R.id.number);


                User newUser = new User();
                newUser.setId(database.getKey());
                newUser.setEmail(email.getText().toString());
                newUser.setPass(pass.getText().toString());
                newUser.setName(name.getText().toString());
                newUser.setNumb(numb.getText().toString());
                database.push().setValue(newUser);

                }
        });
```

Comment: Спасибо, решил чуть по другому