# Ошибка "IOException: Permission denied" при работе с камерой на Android Webview

Tags: android, android-webview

Столкнулся с проблемой с запуском камеры в Webview-приложении на Android.

На странице есть input type="file" с атрибутами: capture="camera" accept="image/*"

При работе через браузер - все ок. Однако в Webview, естественно, это не работает. Использовал клиент webChrhome. При клике на поле ввода открывается проводник файлов без предложения выбора камеры. В логах вижу ошибку, но в manifest указано все, что требуется.

```
E/Webview: Image file creation failed java.io.IOException: Permission denied
    at java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively0(Native Method)
    at java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively(UnixFileSystem.java:281)
    at java.io.File.createTempFile(File.java:2001)
    at com.payou.app.MainActivity.createImageFile(MainActivity.java:178)
    at com.payou.app.MainActivity.access$200(MainActivity.java:28)
    at com.payou.app.MainActivity$2.onShowFileChooser(MainActivity.java:84)
    at Ii4.e(chromium-Monochrome.aab-stable-561513523:31)
    at Hs.runFileChooser(chromium-Monochrome.aab-stable-561513523:28)
    at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
    at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:379)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:144)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7529)
```

Ниже привожу часть manifest и код моей Activiy. Подскажите, в чем может быть еще проблема? Или чего-то не хватает?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA2" />
```

```
            public boolean onShowFileChooser(WebView webView, ValueCallback<Uri[]> filePathCallback, FileChooserParams fileChooserParams) {
                if (mUMA != null) {
                    mUMA.onReceiveValue(null);
                }
                mUMA = filePathCallback;
                Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(MainActivity.this.getPackageManager()) != null) {
                    File photoFile = null;
                    try {
                        photoFile = createImageFile();
                        takePictureIntent.putExtra("PhotoPath", mCM);
                    } catch (IOException ex) {
                        Log.e("Webview", "Image file creation failed", ex);
                    }
                    if (photoFile != null) {
                        mCM = "file:" + photoFile.getAbsolutePath();
                        takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
                    } else {
                        takePictureIntent = null;
                    }
                }

                Intent contentSelectionIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                contentSelectionIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                contentSelectionIntent.setType("*/*");
                Intent[] intentArray;
                if (takePictureIntent != null) {
                    intentArray = new Intent[]{takePictureIntent};
                } else {
                    intentArray = new Intent[0];
                }

                Intent chooserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CHOOSER);
                chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INTENT, contentSelectionIntent);
                chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, "Image Chooser");
                chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, intentArray);
                startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, FCR);
                return true;
            }
```

```
public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg) {
        this.openFileChooser(uploadMsg, "*/*");
    }

    public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg, String acceptType) {
        this.openFileChooser(uploadMsg, acceptType, null);
    }

    public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg, String acceptType, String capture) {
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
        i.setType("*/*");
        MainActivity.this.startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(i, "File Browser"), FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);
    }

@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
            Uri[] results = null;
            //Check if response is positive
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                if (requestCode == FCR) {
                    if (null == mUMA) {
                        return;
                    }
                    if (intent == null) {
                        //Capture Photo if no image available
                        if (mCM != null) {
                            results = new Uri[]{Uri.parse(mCM)};
                        }
                    } else {
                        String dataString = intent.getDataString();
                        if (dataString != null) {
                            results = new Uri[]{Uri.parse(dataString)};
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            mUMA.onReceiveValue(results);
            mUMA = null;
        } else {
            if (requestCode == FCR) {
                if (null == mUM) return;
                Uri result = intent == null || resultCode != RESULT_OK ? null : intent.getData();
                mUM.onReceiveValue(result);
                mUM = null;
            }
        }
    }

    // Create an image file
    private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
        @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat") String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        String imageFileName = "img_" + timeStamp + "_";
        File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
        return File.createTempFile(imageFileName, ".jpg", storageDir);


    }
```

Comment: Предполагаю, что у вас Android 10 или выше. Метод [`getExternalStoragePublicDirectory`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment#getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(java.lang.String)) устарел, нужно использовать [Storage Access Framework](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/document-provider). Приведите полный текст ошибки вместе со [стектрейсом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/797531), чтобы разобраться, в чем конкретно проблема.

Comment: @VadikSirekanyan Попробовал использовать Storage Access Framework. Но при нажатии на поле для загрузки файла открывается просто файловый менеджер (а необходимо, чтобы камера запускалась или хотя бы выбор "файлы" или "камера"). Привел стектрейс ошибок в посте (дополнил)...

Comment: E/Webview: Image file creation failed
    java.io.IOException: Permission denied 
    at java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively0(Native Method)
    at java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively(UnixFileSystem.java:281)
    at java.io.File.createTempFile(File.java:2001)
    at com.payou.app.MainActivity.createImageFile(MainActivity.java:178)
    at com.payou.app.MainActivity.access$200(MainActivity.java:28)

Comment: at com.payou.app.MainActivity$2.onShowFileChooser(MainActivity.java:84)
    at Ii4.e(chromium-Monochrome.aab-stable-561513523:31)
    at Hs.runFileChooser(chromium-Monochrome.aab-stable-561513523:28)
    at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
    at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:379)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:144)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7529)

Comment: Ошибка в строчке номер `178` файла `MainActivity.java`. Файл не удалось создать по той причине, о которой я написал в первом комментарии. На новых версиях Андроида `getExternalStoragePublicDirectory` использовать не нужно. Если вы уже обсуждаете новый код, который написали, то создайте [новый вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) и покажите этот код.

Comment: 1) незачем временный файл создавать в публичной директории - для этого лучше использовать приватную. 2) `Uri` со схемой `file` шарить между приложениями запрещено, приложение камеры не сможет в него сохранить фото. Собственно пример запроса с пояснениями есть в гайде: https://developer.android.com/training/camera-deprecated/photobasics#TaskPath