# Ошибка ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException при работе с DropdownMenu

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

У меня есть в коде dropDownMenu и при выборе опции почему то вылетает, код:

```
            Box(){
            Text(text = selectedOption, color = Colors().TextWhite, fontSize = 14.sp)
            DropdownMenu(expanded = expanded, onDismissRequest = { expanded = false }) {
                var i = 0
                repeat(values.size)
                {

                    DropdownMenuItem(onClick = {
                        selectedOption = values[i]
                        expanded = false
                    }) {
                        Text(
                            values[i], fontSize = 18.sp, modifier = Modifier
                                .padding(10.dp)
                        )
                    }
                I++}
            }
        }
```

Но что забавно, если поменять `selectedOption = values[i]` на, например `selectedOption = values[0]` или `selectedOption = "Что-нибудь"`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
            Box(){
            Text(text = selectedOption, color = Colors().TextWhite, fontSize = 14.sp)
            DropdownMenu(expanded = expanded, onDismissRequest = { expanded = false }) {
                var i = -1
                repeat(values.size)
                {
                    i += 1
                    DropdownMenuItem(onClick = {
                        selectedOption = i.toString()
                        expanded = false
                    }) {
                        Text(
                            i.toString(), fontSize = 18.sp, modifier = Modifier
                                .padding(10.dp)
                        )
                    }


                }
            }
        }
```

а при таком коде, в обе опции он записывает последнее значение.

Comment: Чтобы не гадать, почему вылетает, покажите текст ошибки и [стектрейс](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/797531). Добавьте его [в вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1519603/edit).

Comment: Изменил) @VadikSirekanyan

Comment: Вы пытаетесь получить элемент массива с индексом 2, хотя в массиве всего 2 элемента (с индексами 0 и 1). Вы где-то меняете `i`, но этого кода нет в вопросе. Покажите в вопросе код, где меняется `i`.

Comment: @VadikSirekanyan Извиняюсь, забыл эту строчку. В том то и немонимание. Почему оно работает 3 раза? Repeat - 2 значит у меня будет values[0], values[1],  и i =2, но в значение же она не пойдет. Код в вопросе поменял

Comment: Добавил еще 1 код. Почему так получается, я понять не могу...

Comment: что лежит в `values`? Какое значение `values.size`?

Comment: Ваш пример не удается воспроизвести, так как неизвестно, как определяется `values` и что такое переменная `I`. Сделайте [mre], который демонстрирует вашу проблему, чтобы другие участники могли повторить эту ошибку.

Answer (score 0):

В итоге все дело было в repeat. Заменил на for и все стало работать, магия...

```
Box(){
            values = listOf<String>("1","2")
            Text(text = selectedOption, color = Colors().TextWhite, fontSize = 14.sp)
            DropdownMenu(expanded = expanded, onDismissRequest = { expanded = false }) {
                for(i in 0 .. values.size-1)
                {
                    DropdownMenuItem(onClick = {
                        selectedOption = values[i]
                        expanded = false
                    }) {
                        Text(
                            values[i], fontSize = 18.sp, modifier = Modifier
                                .padding(10.dp)
                        )
                    }


                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Подкрепите ваш ответ кодом, как было и как стало?

Comment: Изменил, @VadikSirekanyan

Answer (score 0):

Возможно, вы где-то напутали с индексами, чтобы избежать подобных ошибок, удалите `var i` и используйте `index` в функции [`repeat`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/repeat.html):

```kotlin
repeat(values.size) { index ->
    println(values[index])
}
```

Так как `index` вам по сути не нужен, то еще лучше использовать [`forEach`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/for-each.html) для коллекции `values`. В таком случае еще сложнее будет допустить ошибок с индексами:

```kotlin
values.forEach { value ->
    println(value)
}
```