# Кастомный виджет в Android с масштабированием

Tags: android, kotlin

Я пытаюсь сделать виджет который будет динамически подгружаемой картой. Но пока я поставил заглушку в виде картинки из настроек и пытаюсь написать масштабирование. Я перехожу в эту активность из другой, и у меня крашит после загрузки активности с этим виджетом.

```
class Map(context: Context) : View(context) {
    private var dynamicMap: Array<Array<Tail>>? = null
    private var lazyDynamicMap: Array<Array<Tail>>? = null
    private var viewMap: Bitmap? = null
    private var screenWidth: Int = 0
    private var screenHeight: Int = 0
    private var mapScaleFactor: Float = 1f
    private var lastScaleFactor: Float = 1f
    private var scaleGestureDetector: ScaleGestureDetector

    init {
        scaleGestureDetector = ScaleGestureDetector(context, object : ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener() {
            override fun onScale(detector: ScaleGestureDetector): Boolean {
                mapScaleFactor *= detector.scaleFactor / lastScaleFactor
                lastScaleFactor = detector.scaleFactor
                invalidate()
                return true
            }

            override fun onScaleEnd(detector: ScaleGestureDetector) {
                lastScaleFactor = 1f
            }
        })

        // Получение инициализации viewMap из ресурсов
        viewMap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources, R.drawable.img_bg_setting)

        // Получение ширины и высоты экрана
        val displayMetrics = resources.displayMetrics
        screenWidth = displayMetrics.widthPixels
        screenHeight = displayMetrics.heightPixels
    }

    override fun onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec: Int, heightMeasureSpec: Int) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec)
        val desiredWidth = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec)
        val desiredHeight = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec)
        setMeasuredDimension(desiredWidth, desiredHeight)
    }

    override fun onTouchEvent(event: MotionEvent): Boolean {
        scaleGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event)
        return true
    }

    override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas)
        viewMap?.let {
            val scaledWidth = it.width * mapScaleFactor
            val scaledHeight = it.height * mapScaleFactor
            val left = (width - scaledWidth) / 2
            val top = (height - scaledHeight) / 2
            canvas.drawBitmap(it, null, RectF(left, top, left + scaledWidth, top + scaledHeight), null)
        }
    }
}
```

XML-вёрстка:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".###">

    <com.###.Map
        android:id="@+id/###"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Заранее скажу, что среда не ругается на какие-либо красные ошибки.
Разве что пишет вот это в XML-вёрстке:
`Missing classes`

```
The following classes could not be found:
- com.###.Map (Fix Build Path, Edit XML, Create Class)
   Tip: Try to build the project.
   Tip: Try to refresh the layout.
```

Работаю через Android Studio. Gradle нормально проект собирает. Вместо `###` - ID приложения, там тоже всё указано правильно.
Карта будет собираться путём склеивания из тайлов из `dynamicMap`, `lazyDynamicMap` - будет хранить б`ольшую площадь, но после отрисовки основной.

Comment: Когда крашит - полагается смотреть в логи и если причина вам не понятна, то прикладывать [лог ошибки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/797531/11515) к вопросу. Чтобы использовать свой класс в разметке нужно объявить конструктор с двумя параметрами [`View(context: Context!, attrs: AttributeSet?)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/view/View#View(android.content.Context,%20android.util.AttributeSet)) - без него инфлейтер не может создать экземпляр этого класса.

Comment: @woesss, вот я не понял, где смотреть эти логи.

Comment: Я вам ссылку дал на вопрос, где всё написано. В LogCat нужно смотреть: https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/logcat

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка оказалась не в том, что говорил @woesss. Но я и сам хорош, сказал что всё правильно остальное. Gradle при сборке не клонирует стили, а Android не позволяет одному стилю использоваться несколько раз.
У меня же было наследование стиля. Я добавил ещё один персонально для этой активности и всё заработало.