# Крашит приложение при переходе на новое активити android

Tags: android, binding

На данных строках

```kotlin
class SecondActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding: SecondActivityBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        binding = SecondActivityBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)
```

крашит приложение, при этом по клику через ctrl все видит. Кто-то встречался с подобной проблемой.

Comment: Для начала лог в студию https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/797531/11515

Comment: Скорее всего в манифесте прописать забыли