обработчик события для SharedPreferences
мне нужно сохранить несколько String переменных в SharedPreferences. В переменную String записываются значения из EditText. Если поля пусты приложение вылетает то ли из-за getText при записывании в String, то ли из-за занесения строки в SharedPreferences.
Возможно ли это сделать через try catch? или как то по другому;
в logcat вот это:
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                                Process: com.example.tstu, PID: 22535
                                                                                                java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.tstu/com.example.tstu.scheduleSet}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.text.Editable android.widget.EditText.getText()' on a null object reference
                                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3903)
                                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4049)
                                                                                                    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:101)
                                                                                                    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
                                                                                                    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
                                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2443)
                                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
                                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:211)
                                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:300)
                                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8348)
                                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:582)
                                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1028)
                                                                                                Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.text.Editable android.widget.EditText.getText()' on a null object reference
                                                                                                    at com.example.tstu.scheduleSet.onCreate(scheduleSet.java:104)
                                                                                                    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8577)
                                                                                                    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8541)
                                                                                                    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1437)
                                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3884)
                                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4049) 
                                                                                                    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:101) 
                                                                                                    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
                                                                                                    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
                                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2443) 
                                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
                                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:211) 
                                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:300) 
                                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8348) 
                                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:582) 
                                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1028) 


if(editText.getText().toString().isEmpty(){}else{тут записывание} - пытался сделать так, но все равно вылетает

Что делать когда вылетает: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/797531/11515

У вас переменная editText не инициализирована на момент обращения к ней. И в onCreate брать текст из полей ввода бессмысленно - они пустые. Чтобы получить более конкретный ответ - покажите свой код.
