# Как разобраться в ошибках Angular

Tags: angular2, angular, angular4

Подскажите как понимать ошибки в ангуляре когда он даже не пишет в каком месте кода они происходят, я делал проект (а я плохо разбираюсь и долго делаю) и все было нормально все работало, одним прекрасным утром завел команду ng serve -o и ангуляр мне выдал вот такую фигню

```
main.ts:12 Error: No base href set. Please provide a value for the APP_BASE_HREF token or add a base element to the document.
    at new PathLocationStrategy (common.js:406)
    at provideLocationStrategy (router.js:5440)
    at _callFactory (core.js:19852)
    at _createProviderInstance (core.js:19804)
    at initNgModule (core.js:19734)
    at new NgModuleRef_ (core.js:20461)
    at createNgModuleRef (core.js:20450)
    at Object.debugCreateNgModuleRef [as createNgModuleRef] (core.js:22281)
    at NgModuleFactory_.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.NgModuleFactory_.create (core.js:23009)
    at core.js:16622
```

И что с этим делать непонятно, в гугле гуглю и толку нет и так постоянно, то есть фрейм кайфовый но если вылезла ошибка то хрен разберешь откуда и почему.

Может кто подскажет как с этим бороться, фреймворк же должен облегчать работу и ускорять а я на нативном JS быстрее пишу потому что если там словил клюк то хотябы понятно где он=)

решение то этой ошибки я нашел, в главном HTML файле, в который сроду никогда не был куда то пропала вот такая штука `<base href="/">` но осадок остался, 2 дня копаний в гугле и это со знанием английского=(

Comment: просто погуглите что такое stack trace

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/510755/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-stack-trace-%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81-%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D1%8C%D1%8E-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6

Comment: `в гугле гуглю и толку нет и так постоянно` - вы обманываете, если вбить в гугле `No base href set. Please provide a value for the APP_BASE_HREF token or add a base element to the document` - там будет `Результатов: примерно 9 250` и [самая первая ссылка](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34535163/angular-2-router-no-base-href-set), скорее всего не гуглите :)

Comment: суть этого вопроса не в данной ошибке, ответ я в гугле нашел, пользоваться умею еще раз! я в целом об ошибках, у меня еще штук пять которые я не могу разобрать потому что инфы нету совсем. к примеру еще одна  - unresolved function or method post() - это выдает вэб шторм при написание сервиса и метода post, причем сервис идентичный такому же в другом проекте и структура та же (вобщем для большего понимания переписываю проект строчка за строчкой) но откуда эта ошибка и что с ней делать попробуйте нагуглить! результат выдает null