# Get запрос в Retrofit2

Tags: android, retrofit2

Использую Retrofit2 для получения json данных [отсюда](https://api.github.com/users). При запуске метода onCreate(в котором и выполняется запрос) выводит тост из onFailure. Подскажите где не так я поступил?

MainActivity

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar_main);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    ListView listViewMain = findViewById(R.id.list_view_main);

    final TextView tvLogin, tvName, tvId;
    tvId = findViewById(R.id.user_id);
    tvName = findViewById(R.id.user_name);
    tvLogin = findViewById(R.id.user_login);

    NetworkService.getInstance().usersAPI().getUsers().enqueue(new Callback<UserClass>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<UserClass> call, Response<UserClass> response) {
            UserClass userClass = response.body();

            tvLogin.append(userClass.getLogin());
            tvName.append(userClass.getHtmlUrl());

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<UserClass> call, Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Не получилось", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```

NetworkServise

```
public class NetworkService {
    private static NetworkService networkService;
    private static String BASE_URL = "https://api.github.com";
    private Retrofit retrofit;

    private NetworkService() {
        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
    }

    public static NetworkService getInstance() {
        if (networkService == null) {
            networkService = new NetworkService();
        }
        return networkService;
    }

    public UsersAPI usersAPI() {
        return retrofit.create(UsersAPI.class);
    }
}
```

Интерфейс usersApi

```
public interface UsersAPI {
    @GET("/users")
    Call<UserClass> getUsers();
}
```

И класс UserClass, который используется в интерфейсе (с помощью сайта jsonschema2pojo)

```
public class UserClass {
    @SerializedName("login")
    @Expose
    private String login;
    @SerializedName("id")
    @Expose
    private Integer id;
    @SerializedName("node_id")
    @Expose
    private String nodeId;
    @SerializedName("avatar_url")
    @Expose
    private String avatarUrl;
    @SerializedName("gravatar_id")
    @Expose
    private String gravatarId;
    @SerializedName("url")
    @Expose
    private String url;
    @SerializedName("html_url")
    @Expose
    private String htmlUrl;
    @SerializedName("followers_url")
    @Expose
    private String followersUrl;
    @SerializedName("following_url")
    @Expose
    private String followingUrl;
    @SerializedName("gists_url")
    @Expose
    private String gistsUrl;
    @SerializedName("starred_url")
    @Expose
    private String starredUrl;
    @SerializedName("subscriptions_url")
    @Expose
    private String subscriptionsUrl;
    @SerializedName("organizations_url")
    @Expose
    private String organizationsUrl;
    @SerializedName("repos_url")
    @Expose
    private String reposUrl;
    @SerializedName("events_url")
    @Expose
    private String eventsUrl;
    @SerializedName("received_events_url")
    @Expose
    private String receivedEventsUrl;
    @SerializedName("type")
    @Expose
    private String type;
    @SerializedName("site_admin")
    @Expose
    private Boolean siteAdmin;

    public String getLogin() {
        return login;
    }

    public void setLogin(String login) {
        this.login = login;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getNodeId() {
        return nodeId;
    }

    public void setNodeId(String nodeId) {
        this.nodeId = nodeId;
    }

    public String getAvatarUrl() {
        return avatarUrl;
    }

    public void setAvatarUrl(String avatarUrl) {
        this.avatarUrl = avatarUrl;
    }

    public String getGravatarId() {
        return gravatarId;
    }

    public void setGravatarId(String gravatarId) {
        this.gravatarId = gravatarId;
    }

    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }

    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }

    public String getHtmlUrl() {
        return htmlUrl;
    }

    public void setHtmlUrl(String htmlUrl) {
        this.htmlUrl = htmlUrl;
    }

    public String getFollowersUrl() {
        return followersUrl;
    }

    public void setFollowersUrl(String followersUrl) {
        this.followersUrl = followersUrl;
    }

    public String getFollowingUrl() {
        return followingUrl;
    }

    public void setFollowingUrl(String followingUrl) {
        this.followingUrl = followingUrl;
    }

    public String getGistsUrl() {
        return gistsUrl;
    }

    public void setGistsUrl(String gistsUrl) {
        this.gistsUrl = gistsUrl;
    }

    public String getStarredUrl() {
        return starredUrl;
    }

    public void setStarredUrl(String starredUrl) {
        this.starredUrl = starredUrl;
    }

    public String getSubscriptionsUrl() {
        return subscriptionsUrl;
    }

    public void setSubscriptionsUrl(String subscriptionsUrl) {
        this.subscriptionsUrl = subscriptionsUrl;
    }

    public String getOrganizationsUrl() {
        return organizationsUrl;
    }

    public void setOrganizationsUrl(String organizationsUrl) {
        this.organizationsUrl = organizationsUrl;
    }

    public String getReposUrl() {
        return reposUrl;
    }

    public void setReposUrl(String reposUrl) {
        this.reposUrl = reposUrl;
    }

    public String getEventsUrl() {
        return eventsUrl;
    }

    public void setEventsUrl(String eventsUrl) {
        this.eventsUrl = eventsUrl;
    }

    public String getReceivedEventsUrl() {
        return receivedEventsUrl;
    }

    public void setReceivedEventsUrl(String receivedEventsUrl) {
        this.receivedEventsUrl = receivedEventsUrl;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public Boolean getSiteAdmin() {
        return siteAdmin;
    }

    public void setSiteAdmin(Boolean siteAdmin) {
        this.siteAdmin = siteAdmin;
    }
}
```

Ошибка:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 2 path $
    at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.beginObject(JsonReader.java:385)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:213)
```

Comment: залогируйте ошибку из onFailure и приложите сюда текст логов https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/510755/Что-такое-stack-trace-и-как-с-его-помощью-находить-ошибки-при-разработке-прилож?rq=1

Comment: @Alex_Skvortsov ошибки нет, в том то и дело. Просто выводится текст из тоста в onFailure. То есть, приложение работает, но не отправляет запрос

Comment: @Alex_Skvortsov Вы меня слышите? Как я вам скину лог ошибки, если её нет? ПРИЛОЖЕНИЕ НЕ ВЫЛЕТАЕТ. ЗАПРОС ВЫПОЛНЯЕТСЯ НЕПРАВИЛЬНО

Comment: @ТагирИдрисов, кажется, вы не вывели в лог сообщение об ошибке. Добавьте перед тоастом вот эту строку: `t.printStackTrace()` - и после этого приложите к вопросу красный текст из `logCat`

Comment: Если произошла ошибка, то это не значит, что приложение должно вылетать. В частности ошибки можно ловить с помощью `try catch`. У вас при запросе как раз произошла ошибка и вызвался метод `onFailure`, в который и передаётся ошибка `Throwable t`. Посмотрите что выводит `t.getMessage()`

Answer (score 2):

Api возвращает список, а Вы указали в возвращаемом типе объект, замените

```
public interface UsersAPI {
    @GET("/users")
    Call<UserClass> getUsers();
}
```

на

```
public interface UsersAPI {
    @GET("/users")
    Call<ArrayList<UserClass>> getUsers();
}
```

И соответствующим образом измените остальной код, вызывающий эту функцию.

То, что видно в Вашем вопросе Можно поменять так:

```
NetworkService.getInstance().usersAPI().getUsers().enqueue(new Callback<ArrayList<UserClass>>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<ArrayList<UserClass>> call, Response<ArrayList<UserClass>> response) {
        ArrayList<UserClass> userClassArray = response.body();

        tvLogin.append(userClassArray[0].getLogin());//будет ошибка при пустом списке
        tvName.append(userClassArray[0].getHtmlUrl());

    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<ArrayList<UserClass>> call, Throwable t) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Не получилось", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

Comment: Это java-код? Может вы имели в виду `ArrayList<UserClass>`?

Comment: @woesss благодарю, я ошибся)