# Приложение крашится при передаче данных из диалогового окна

Tags: android

Мне нужно передать данные из EditText, находящихся в диалоговом окне
Мой код:
1.Создаю диалоговое окно:

```
goCreateTask = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
goCreateTask.setContentView(R.layout.choose_task);
goCreateTask.setCancelable(false);
```

2.Объявляю EditText:

```
nameUserTask = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.name_for_user_task);
numberOfUserRepetitions = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.repetition_for_user_task);
```

3.Передаю значения из EditText в String:

```
nameTask = nameUserTask.getText().toString();
numberOfRepetitions = numberOfUserRepetitions.getText().toString();
```

Программа падает на передаче данных из "EditText" в "String", не знаю в чём дело.

Comment: Что выдает LogCat? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/510755/Что-такое-stack-trace-и-как-с-его-помощью-находить-ошибки-при-разработке-прилож?rq=1 и еще https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/797531/У-меня-просят-стектрейс-stack-trace-или-логкат-logcat-Что-это?rq=1

Comment: Вы ищите в разметке активити или фрагмента, а надо в разметке диалога