# JPA Service выкидывает nullpointer

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, service

Проблема заключается в том, что созданный объект не отправляется в бд  и выдает NPE.

Класс Cargo:

```
@Entity
public class Cargo {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    @Column(name = "activity")
    private String activity;

    @Column(name = "status")
    private String status;

    @Column(name = "cargoNumber")
    private String cargoNumber;

    @Column(name = "cargoType")
    private String cargoType;

    @Column(name = "outboundtruck")
    private String outBoundTruck;

    @Column(name = "inboundtruck")
    private String inBoundTruck;

    @Column(name = "masterCargo")
    private String masterCargo;

    @Column(name = "contentType")
    private String contentType;

    @Column(name = "supplier")
    private String supplier;

    @Column(name = "consignee")
    private String consignee;

    @Column(name = "address")
    private String address;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST})
    @JoinColumn(name = "masterCargoId", nullable = false)
    private MasterCargo masterCargos;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "inboundTruckCargo",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "cargoId", referencedColumnName = "id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "inboundTruckId", referencedColumnName = "id"))
    private Set<InboundTruck> inboundTrucks;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "outboundTruckCargo",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "cargoId", referencedColumnName = "id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "outboundTruckId", referencedColumnName = "id"))
    private Set<OutBoundTruck> outBoundTrucks;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "cargos")
    private Set<Orders> orders;
    --getters and setters--
}
```

CargoService

```
import com.fmlogostic.simpleXdocTest.entity.Cargo;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.List;

@Service
public interface CargoService {

    Cargo addCargo(Cargo cargo);
    void delete(Long id);
    Cargo getByNumber(String number);
    Cargo editCargo(Cargo cargo);
    List<Cargo> getAll();

}
```

CargoServiceImpl

```
@Service
public class CargoServiceImpl implements CargoService {

    @Autowired
    private CargoRepository cargoRepository;

    @Override
    public Cargo addCargo(Cargo cargo) {

        return cargoRepository.saveAndFlush(cargo);
    }

    @Override
    public void delete(Long id) {
        cargoRepository.deleteById(id);
    }

    @Override
    public Cargo getByNumber(String number) {
        return null;
    }


    @Override
    public Cargo editCargo(Cargo cargo) {
        return cargoRepository.saveAndFlush(cargo);
    }

    @Override
    public List<Cargo> getAll() {
        return cargoRepository.findAll();
    }
}
```

CargoRepository

```
@Repository
public interface CargoRepository extends JpaRepository<Cargo, Long> {
}
```

и сам класс с созданием объекта

```
@Controller
public class JSONprsController {

    @Transient
    @Autowired
    private CargoServiceImpl cargoService;

    private static final Logger logger =
            LoggerFactory.getLogger(JSONprsController.class);

    public String create(String JSONstring) throws ParseException {

        JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) JSONValue.parseWithException(JSONstring);
        JSONArray cargos = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("cargos");

        Orders orders = new Orders();
        try {

            String activity = "test";
            String status = "test";
            String cargoNumber = "test";
            String cargoType = "test";
            String outBoundTruck = "test";
            String inboundTruck = "test";
            String masterCargo = "test";
            String contentType = "test";
            String supplier = "test";
            String consignee = "test";
            String address = "test";
            Cargo cargo = new Cargo(activity, status, cargoNumber, cargoType, outBoundTruck, inboundTruck, masterCargo, contentType, supplier, consignee, address);

            logger.info(cargo.toString());
            cargoService.addCargo(cargo);
        } catch (NullPointerException e){
            logger.info("Null");
        }
        return "order";
    }
```

Консоль без try-catch

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at com.fmlogostic.simpleXdocTest.JSONprsController.create(JSONprsController.java:56) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.fmlogostic.simpleXdocTest.Controllers.JsonController.jsonPost(JsonController.java:30) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190) ~[spring-web-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138) ~[spring-web-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:105) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:879) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:793) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:373) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1594) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832) ~[na:na]
```

Answer (score 0):

Думаю, что ошибка возникает не в JPA-сервисе, как вы указали, а контроллере JSONprsController в методе create на 56 строчке.

Возможно, вам будет полезна информация по этой ссылке:
[Что такое stack trace, и как с его помощью находить ошибки при разработке приложений?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/510755/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-stack-trace-%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81-%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D1%8C%D1%8E-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6)

А так же это:
[Что такое Null Pointer Exception и как его исправить?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/511085/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-null-pointer-exception-%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C)

Comment: да, NPE возникает на строке, где я хочу отправить объект в БД. то есть на `cargoService.addCargo(cargo);`, вопрос в том, как правильно сохранить объект в БД

Comment: Видимо, ваш cargoService == null. Почему так случилось и что делать, вам поможет ссылка: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19896870/why-is-my-spring-autowired-field-null

Comment: `вопрос в том, как правильно сохранить объект в БД`

Вы правильно сохраняете объект в БД, но неправильно сконфигурировали бин CargoServiceImpl или из-за того, что в спринговой конфигурации в аннотации @ComponentScan не указан пакет, в котором находится CargoServiceImpl

Comment: проставил в JSONprsController "@Service и @Configurable", в файл конфигурации прописал "@EnableSpringConfigured и указал весь каталог в @componentScan" но после выполнения метода все равно ловлю NPE :(

Comment: NPE ловите в том же самом месте или уже в другом?
Вы проверили, что в debug-режиме @Autowired поле cargoService == null?

Comment: да, в Дебаге и this-cargoService = null, и просто cargoService = null, при чем объект в нем не пустой