# Не могу создать подключение к любому URL | Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

Пытаюсь создать интернет подключение к сайту. Сервер сайта работает, а вот запрос через Kotlin не очень. Пробовал все способы, но не один метод не помог. Буду дать вашу помощь. В Manifest есть разрешение.
При попытке отправить запрос я получаю :

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.quenzer.executeapp, PID: 27926
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:414)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7217)
    at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1119)
    at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7191)
    at android.view.View.access$3500(View.java:828)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27679)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:900)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:219)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8349)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:513)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1055)
 Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:409)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7217) 
    at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1119) 
    at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7191) 
    at android.view.View.access$3500(View.java:828) 
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27679) 
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:900) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:219) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8349) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:513) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1055) 
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl cannot be cast to javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection
    at com.quenzer.executeapp.MainActivity.Execute(MainActivity.kt:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:409) 
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7217) 
    at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1119) 
    at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7191) 
    at android.view.View.access$3500(View.java:828) 
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27679) 
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:900) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:219) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8349) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:513) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1055)
```

Сам код.

```
package com.quenzer.executeapp

import android.os.Build
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View
import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
import java.net.URL
import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection


private lateinit var Input: TextInputEditText

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        Input = findViewById(R.id.TextInput)
    }

    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    fun Execute(view: View) {
        val countString = Input.text.toString()
        // val url = URL("http://v913463x.beget.tech/index.php?Text=$countString")
        val url = URL("http://v913463x.beget.tech/index.php?Text=$countString")
        var connection = url.openConnection() as HttpsURLConnection
        connection.setRequestMethod("GET") // установка метода получения данных -GET
        connection.setReadTimeout(10000) // установка таймаута перед выполнением - 10 000 миллисекунд
        connection.connect() // подключаемся к ресурсу
    }

}
```

Comment: У вас сайт по http, а вы пытаетесь открыть его через HttpsURLConnection. Либо HttpUrlConnection, либо сайт по https.

Comment: В ошибке у вас написано, что класс `com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl` не может быть приведен к классу `javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection`. И даже указано, что это происходит в 27 строке вашего кода. Уберите приведение типа `as HttpsURLConnection`, падает из-за этого.

Answer (score 0):

Доходим до последнего `Caused by` в стектрейсе и видим:

```
Caused by: ClassCastException: HttpURLConnectionImpl cannot be cast to HttpsURLConnection
    at com.quenzer.executeapp.MainActivity.Execute(MainActivity.kt:27)
```

Это означает, что в вашем классе `MainActivity.kt` на строчке `27` произошло исключение [ClassCastException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ClassCastException.html). А именно, не удалось тип `HttpURLConnectionImpl` привести к типу `HttpsURLConnection`.

Чтобы двигаться дальше, уберите приведение типа `as HttpsURLConnection`.

Вот [этот ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/510756) поможет вам разобраться, как читать стектрейсы.