# Реализация метода remove() в собственном двухсвязном списке LinkedList

Tags: java, linked-list, двусвязный-список

Друзья, привет! Помогите разобраться. При удалении элемента из двухсвязного списка возникает ошибка - Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot read field "value" because "current" is null

Ошибка возникает в работе метода get(), так как один элемент из списка удален, а get() "об этом не узнает" и выводит первоначальный список.

Не пойму, в какой строчке get() поставить ограничение вывода значений до момента != null ?

```
    @Override
    public T get(int i) {
        if (i < 0 || i >= length ()) {
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException ();
        }
        Node<T> current = first;
        for(int j=0; j<i; j++) {
            current = current.next;
        }
       return current.value;
    }

    @Override
    public void remove(T e) {
        Node<T> current = first;
        while (current.value != e) {
            current = current.next;
            if (current == null) {
                throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException ();
            }
        }
        if (current.next != null) {
            current.next.prev = current.prev;
        }
        current.prev.next = current.next;
    }
```

Comment: Воспользуйтесь отладчиком и узнаете

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Что такое Null Pointer Exception и как его исправить?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/511085/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b5-null-pointer-exception-%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c)

Comment: Посмотрите [стектрейс](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/510755/) ошибки, чтобы узнать, на какой строчке возникло исключение.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        if (current == null) {
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException ();
        }
```

Кого Вы здесь хотите запутать? Надо:

```
        if (current == null) {
            throw new ValueNotFoundException();
        }
```

---

```
@Override
public void remove(T e) {
    Node<T> current = first;
    while (current != null && current.value != e) {
        current = current.next;
    }
    if (current == null) {
        throw new ValueNotFoundException();
    }
    if (current.next != null) {
        current.next.prev = current.prev;
    }
    if (current.prev != null) {
        current.prev.next = current.next;
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, по архитектуре кода remove() у Вас правильнее. Но ошибка не исчезла, она появляется в методе get() при вызове оператора return.

Comment: @Dmitriy "При удалении элемента из двухсвязного списка возникает ошибка" - ??

Comment: Да, при удалении элемента из двухсвязного списка. При вызове метода remove() возникает ошибка в выполнении метода get().

Comment: @Dmitriy Хорошо. Сейчас я догадаюсь. Вы не обновляете количество элементов, и `length()` возвращает неправильное число.

Comment: Да, похоже... Дело в том, что в задании выше я указал только часть кода из общего задания.

Реализовать структуру двусвязного списка, реализовав интерфейс:
public interface List<T> {
    T get(int i);
    void put(T e);
    void put(int i, T e);
    void remove(int i);
    void remove(T e);
    int length();
}

Удалось выяснить, что при добавлении новых элементов в двусвязный список нужно использовать HashMap.

Comment: @Dmitriy Что делает `length()`?

Comment: `HashMap` тут ни при чем.

Comment: length() возвращает количество элементов в двусвязном списке

Comment: @Dmitriy Это я и сам понимаю. Что он делает внутри?

Comment: Для него переопределен метод из интерфейса
Override
    public int length() {
        return size;
    }
В  main создается объект, который выводит список в консоль 
for (int i = 0; i < list.length(); i++) {
            System.out.println (list.get (i));
        }

Comment: @Dmitriy Я так и думал. Что Вы думаете о приведении `size` в соответствие с новым количеством элементов при удалении элемента?

Comment: хороший вопрос... спасибо за совет, сейчас подумаю...

Comment: @Dmitriy Пожалуйста. Знак "галочка" - слева от ответа.