# Android. Как кастомизировать Spinner ПРАВИЛЬНО?

Tags: android, adapter, customview, arrayadapter

Активность:

```
        package mate.files;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class WelcomeActionBarAppearance extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getSupportActionBar().hide(); // Disable window title
        Spinner BarType = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.BarType); // Spinner init

        ArrayAdapter<?> Adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.ActionBarType,
                        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        Adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    BarType.setAdapter(Adapter);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_welcome_action_bar);

    }
}
```

---

Код simple_spinner_item и simple_spinner_dropdown_item:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Options"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="23sp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

---

Запуск приложения: при попытке перехода на активность с адаптером, приложение вылетает. Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Как минимум, ошибка в том, что `findViewById()` вызван до `setContentView()`. Все операции поиска и обращения к вью элементам должны осуществляться **после** установки макета в окно.

Comment: На будущее, что делать когда вылетает: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/797531/11515, https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/510755/11515. После прочтения и попытки решить самостоятельно, идти сюда строго со стектрейсом

Comment: @woess, ок, теперь не вылетает, но... в simple_spinner_item указан размер шрифта 25sp, но он, почему-то, не применяется к моему Spinner'у.

Comment: Потому что вы указали адаптеру использовать макет из фреймворка (**android**.R.layout.simple_spinner_item), а не свой. Так же вам нужно указать id вашего TextView, так как он у вас в контейнере.