# Вылетает приложение при нажатие на кнопки Android

Tags: java, android, xml

Я делаю экран входа для своего приложения, в итоге у меня два активити, одна просто для входа, другая для регистрации, проблема в том что при нажатии на кнопки приложение сразу же закрывается и все, в чем может быть проблема?

Вот код:
Экран входа:

```
package com.example.afec;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnFailureListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;


public class MainActivityEntrance extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    // Обьявление об использовании следующих обьектов:
    Button button_create;
    TextView textForgot;
    Button button_enter;
    FirebaseAuth auth;
    FirebaseDatabase db;
    DatabaseReference users;
    EditText editEntranceTextTextEmailAddress;
    EditText editEntranceTextTextPassword3;
    RelativeLayout root;


    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_entrance);

        button_create = findViewById(R.id.button_create);
        button_create.setOnClickListener(this);
        textForgot = findViewById(R.id.textForgot);
        textForgot.setOnClickListener(this);

        button_enter = findViewById(R.id.button_enter);
        auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        users = db.getReference("Users");
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(editEntranceTextTextEmailAddress.getText().toString())) {
            Snackbar.make(root, "Введите вашу почту", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }
        if (editEntranceTextTextPassword3.getText().toString().length() < 5) {
            Snackbar.make(root, "Короткий пороль, введите болешь 5 символов", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }
        auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(editEntranceTextTextEmailAddress.getText().toString(), editEntranceTextTextPassword3.getText().toString())
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(AuthResult authResult) {
                        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivityEntrance.this, MainActivityForgotPassword.class));
                        finish();
                    }
                })
                .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        Snackbar.make(root, "Ошибка авторизации. " + e.getMessage(), Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });


    }

}
```

Экран регистрации

```
package com.example.afec;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

import com.example.afec.Models.User;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;

import java.util.Objects;


public class MainActivityCreateAccount extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    Button button_create_account;
    FirebaseAuth auth;
    FirebaseDatabase db;
    DatabaseReference users;
    EditText editCreateAccountTextTextEmailAddress;
    EditText editCreateAccountTextTextPassword3;
    RelativeLayout root;

    @SuppressLint("MissingInflatedId")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_create_account);

        button_create_account = findViewById(R.id.button_create_account);
        button_create_account.setOnClickListener(this);
        auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        users = db.getReference("Users");
        editCreateAccountTextTextEmailAddress = findViewById(R.id.editEntranceTextTextEmailAddress);
        editCreateAccountTextTextPassword3 = findViewById(R.id.editEntranceTextTextPassword3);
        root = findViewById(R.id.root_element);


    }

    @SuppressLint("NonConstantResourceId")
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(editCreateAccountTextTextEmailAddress.getText().toString())) {
            Snackbar.make(root, "Введите вашу почту", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }
        if (editCreateAccountTextTextPassword3.getText().toString().length() < 5) {
            Snackbar.make(root, "Короткий пороль, введите болешь 5 символов", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }

        // Регистрация
        auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(editCreateAccountTextTextEmailAddress.getText().toString(), editCreateAccountTextTextPassword3.getText().toString())
        .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(AuthResult authResult) {
                User user = new User();
                user.setEditCreateAccountTextTextEmailAddress(editCreateAccountTextTextEmailAddress.getText().toString());
                user.setEditCreateAccountTextTextPassword3(editCreateAccountTextTextPassword3.getText().toString());

                users.child(Objects.requireNonNull(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser()).getUid())
                        .setValue(user)
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Void unused) {
                        Snackbar.make(root, "Успешная регистрация", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
}
```

XML регистрации

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivityCreateAccount"
    android:background="@color/grey">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/Logo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="236dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="88dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="85dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="88dp"
        android:foregroundGravity="center"
        android:contentDescription="@string/icon"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/editCreateAccountTextTextEmailAddress"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.478"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_logo_foreground"
        tools:ignore="ImageContrastCheck,ImageContrastCheck" />

    <!-- Это текс отвечающий за информирование для создания аккаунта -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textCreateAccount"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/Logo"
        android:layout_marginHorizontal="139dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="@string/createText"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editCreateAccountTextTextEmailAddress"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:foregroundGravity="center"
        android:layout_below="@id/textCreateAccount"
        android:layout_marginStart="88dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="88dp"
        android:background="@drawable/edit_text_style"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/Username_hint"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.485"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints,TouchTargetSizeCheck"
        android:importantForAutofill="no" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editCreateAccountTextTextPassword3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/editCreateAccountTextTextEmailAddress"
        android:layout_marginStart="88dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="88dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
        android:background="@drawable/edit_text_style"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/Password_hint"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button_create_account"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.571"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        tools:ignore="TouchTargetSizeCheck"
        android:importantForAutofill="no" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_create_account"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/editCreateAccountTextTextPassword3"
        android:layout_marginStart="88dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="88dp"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/green"
        android:text="@string/create_on_account_button"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.571"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints,TextContrastCheck,TouchTargetSizeCheck" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

XML входа

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivityEntrance"
    android:background="@color/grey"
    android:id="@+id/root_element">

    <!-- Снизу это Иконка -->

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/Logo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="236dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="88dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="85dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="88dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/icon"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/editEntranceTextTextEmailAddress"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.478"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_logo_foreground"
        tools:ignore="ImageContrastCheck,ImageContrastCheck" />

    <!-- Снизу это поле для ввода электронной почты для входа -->
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editEntranceTextTextEmailAddress"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Logo"
        android:layout_marginStart="88dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="88dp"
        android:background="@drawable/edit_text_style"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/Username_hint"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/editEntranceTextTextPassword3"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/Logo"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.485"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/Logo"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/Logo"
        tools:ignore="TouchTargetSizeCheck"
        android:importantForAutofill="no" />

    <!-- Снизу это поле для ввода пороля для входа -->
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editEntranceTextTextPassword3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editEntranceTextTextEmailAddress"
        android:layout_marginStart="88dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="88dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
        android:background="@drawable/edit_text_style"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/Password_hint"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button_enter"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.571"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editEntranceTextTextEmailAddress"
        tools:ignore="TouchTargetSizeCheck"
        android:importantForAutofill="no" />

    <!-- Это кнопка отвечающая за вход в приложения -->
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_enter"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editEntranceTextTextPassword3"
        android:layout_marginStart="88dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="88dp"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/green"
        android:text="@string/login_hint"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/textForgot"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.571"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editEntranceTextTextPassword3"
        tools:ignore="TouchTargetSizeCheck,TextContrastCheck" />

    <!-- Это кнопка отвечающая за переход на страницу для сброса пороля -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textForgot"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/editEntranceTextTextPassword3"
        android:layout_marginHorizontal="150dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="38sp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:minHeight="48dp"
        android:text="@string/Forgot_hint"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="14sp" />

    <!-- Это текс отвечающий за информирование кнопки о Создании аккаунта -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textCreate"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/editEntranceTextTextEmailAddress"
        android:layout_marginHorizontal="165dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="229dp"
        android:text="@string/no_account_text"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

    <!-- Это кнопка для создание аккаунта, в случае если его нету -->
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_create"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button_enter"
        android:layout_marginStart="105dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="140dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="106dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/white"
        android:text="@string/create_on_account_button"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button_enter"
        tools:ignore="TouchTargetSizeCheck" />





</RelativeLayout>
```

Лог ошибки при нажатии на кнопку

```
022-12-10 22:01:34.284 20990-20990/com.example.afec E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.afec, PID: 20990
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.text.Editable android.widget.EditText.getText()' on a null object reference
        at com.example.afec.MainActivityEntrance.onClick(MainActivityEntrance.java:57)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6597)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6574)
        at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:778)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25885)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

Comment: Для начала прочтите это: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/797532/11515. Потом исправьте вопрос так, чтобы на него можно было ответить. Нужен лог ошибки и тот код, который непосредственно с ней связан. Можно, конечно, в дополнение и весь проект целиком выложить, чтобы его можно было без лишних телодвижений запустить и увидеть вашу ошибку, но потом не жалуйтесь что кто-то его выложит в маркет раньше вас ;) А вот огромные портянки кода, в которых и разобраться сложно и запустить нельзя - не особо помогают получить ответ.

Comment: @woesss спасибо за информацию, проект полностью скинул

Comment: Я сказал "можно в дополнение", но качать и запускать чужие проекты с дисков станет далеко не каждый и ссылка может "протухнуть" - поэтому вся информация необходимая для решения проблемы должна быть непосредственно здесь. Просто проблему нужно локализовать - то есть выкладывать здесь не весь код, а минимально необходимый. Если вы не понимаете как сократить - оставьте как было. Самое главное: **если приложение вылетает - в вопросе должен быть лог ошибки**.

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @Spark Не ложи проекты в яндекс диск. Для этого есть [github](https://github.com) У многих есть гитхаб аккаунты, зайдут, посмотрят, посоветуют по коду. А с Яндекс диска вряд ли кто-либо будет замарачиваться.

Comment: Ну да тут нужен лог ошибки без него не понять

Comment: @woesss Извиняюсь, сильно туплю :(. Лог предоставил

Comment: @VladimirGlinskikh Извиняюсь, все исправил

Comment: @MadokaMagica добавил

Comment: Ну вот теперь всё ясно. Хотя очень внимательный и дотошный посетитель мог бы и по коду это разглядеть - но гораздо проще найти причину по логу ошибки.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Что такое Null Pointer Exception и как его исправить?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/511085/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b5-null-pointer-exception-%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну давайте разберём что написано в сообщении об ошибке.

```
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.text.Editable android.widget.EditText.getText()' on a null object reference
```

Попытка вызова метода `getText()` класса `android.widget.EditText` через ссылку на `null`

```
at com.example.afec.MainActivityEntrance.onClick(MainActivityEntrance.java:57)
```

В методе `onClick()` в классе `com.example.afec.MainActivityEntrance` на строке 57
А на этой строке у нас:

```
if (TextUtils.isEmpty(editCreateAccountTextTextEmailAddress.getText().toString())) {
```

Вспоминаем какой в ошибке указан метод и понимаем что ссылка `editCreateAccountTextTextEmailAddress` и есть наш `null`
А почему? Да потому что значение ей нигде присвоено.
Вы забыли найти поля ввода:

```java
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_entrance);

        editEntranceTextTextEmailAddress = findViewById(R.id.editEntranceTextTextEmailAddress);
        editEntranceTextTextPassword3 = findViewById(R.id.editEntranceTextTextPassword3);
        ...
    }
```

Comment: Блин, какой я не внимательный, я ввел это значение в другое активити, а про это забыл, прошу прощения и благодарю вас, у меня вопрос а как вы поняли в чем ошибка? просто у меня новая ошибка появилась, а спрашивать уже как-то стыдно

Comment: "а как вы поняли в чем ошибка?" - для кого я ответ разжёвывал... :( Почитайте на досуге: [Что такое stack trace, и как с его помощью находить ошибки при разработке приложений?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/510756/11515)