# Ошибка в приложении с календарём

Tags: android

не работает код. Хочу узнать почему приложение крашится. Я хочу менять фон в зависимости от времени года.

```
fon_app = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.fon_app);
    Calendar kalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    int jam = kalendar.get(MONTH);
    if (jam >= DECEMBER && jam < JANUARY) {
        fon_app.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.background_newyearapp);
    }
    else if (jam == FEBRUARY) {
        fon_app.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.zashit);
    }
    else if (jam == MARCH) {
        fon_app.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.background_valentin);
    }

    else if (jam >= APRIL && jam < MAY) {
        fon_app.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.son_image);
    }
    else if (jam >= JUNE && jam < AUGUST) {
        fon_app.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.background_fon_app);
    }

    else {
        fon_app.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.os);
    }
```

Можете пожалуйста помочь.

Comment: Откройте logcat и найдите ошибку, далее либо отредактируйте вопрос, добавив оную, либо самостоятельно согласно https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/510755/

Comment: Фон не меняется в зависимости от времени года

Comment: Пока вы не выложите лог краша, помочь вам будет невозможно.